# is there a difference between class(): and class(object): in python 2.6-3.x?

Tags: class, object, python-2.6, python-3.x

Before py2.6 it's been answered here. [Difference between class foo and class foo(object) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332255/difference-between-class-foo-and-class-fooobject-in-python)

But for python2.6+ and python3.x, is the first one wrong?

`class Foo(): pass` vs `class Foo(object): pass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Python2.6+, before Python 3.0, the former creates an old-style class while the latter creates a new-style class. In Python 3.0, both create a new-style. The first isn't wrong, but for anything before 3.0 it has different semantics than the latter and is typically discouraged.