# Why do Python classes inherit object?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, inheritance

Why does the following class declaration inherit from `object`?

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...
```

Comment: This creates a [new-style class](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle).

Comment: The answer to this question (while simple) is quite difficult to find. Googling things like "python object base class" or similar comes up with pages and pages of tutorials on object oriented programming. Upvoting because this is the first link that led me to the search terms "old vs. new-style python objects"

Comment: For the "how to search for this question" part, [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=python&l=&e=%28object%29&n=&u=stackoverflow.com) is an option.

Answer (score 1236, accepted):

> #### Is there any reason for a class declaration to inherit from `object`?

In Python 3, apart from compatibility between Python 2 and 3, *no reason*. In Python 2, *many reasons*.

---

#### Python 2.x story:

In Python 2.x (from 2.2 onwards) there's two styles of classes depending on the presence or absence of `object` as a base-class:

1. **"classic" style** classes: they don't have `object` as a base class:

   ```
   >>> class ClassicSpam:      # no base class
   ...     pass
   >>> ClassicSpam.__bases__
   ()
   ```
2. **"new" style** classes: they have, directly *or indirectly* (e.g inherit from a [built-in type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)), `object` as a base class:

   ```
   >>> class NewSpam(object):           # directly inherit from object
   ...    pass
   >>> NewSpam.__bases__
   (<type 'object'>,)
   >>> class IntSpam(int):              # indirectly inherit from object...
   ...    pass
   >>> IntSpam.__bases__
   (<type 'int'>,) 
   >>> IntSpam.__bases__[0].__bases__   # ... because int inherits from object  
   (<type 'object'>,)
   ```

Without a doubt, when writing a class you'll *always* want to go for new-style classes. The perks of doing so are numerous, to list some of them:

- [Support for descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). Specifically, the following constructs are made possible with descriptors:

  1. [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod): A method that receives the class as an implicit argument instead of the instance.
  2. [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod): A method that does not receive the implicit argument `self` as a first argument.
  3. properties with [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property): Create functions for managing the getting, setting and deleting of an attribute.
  4. [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots): Saves memory consumptions of a class and also results in faster attribute access. Of course, it does [impose limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#notes-on-using-slots).
- The [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) static method: lets you customize how new class instances are created.
- [Method resolution order (MRO)](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/): in what order the base classes of a class will be searched when trying to resolve which method to call.
- Related to MRO, [`super` calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super). Also see, [`super()` considered super.](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

If you don't inherit from `object`, forget these. A more exhaustive description of the previous bullet points along with other perks of "new" style classes can be found [here](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/).

One of the downsides of new-style classes is that the class itself is more memory demanding. Unless you're creating many class objects, though, I doubt this would be an issue and it's a negative sinking in a sea of positives.

---

#### Python 3.x story:

In Python 3, things are simplified. Only new-style classes exist (referred to plainly as classes) so, the only difference in adding `object` is requiring you to type in 8 more characters. This:

```
class ClassicSpam:
    pass
```

is completely equivalent (apart from their name :-) to this:

```
class NewSpam(object):
     pass
```

and to this:

```
class Spam():
    pass
```

All have `object` in their `__bases__`.

```
>>> [object in cls.__bases__ for cls in {Spam, NewSpam, ClassicSpam}]
[True, True, True]
```

---

### So, what should you do?

**In Python 2:** *always inherit from `object` explicitly*. Get the perks.

**In Python 3:** inherit from `object` if you are writing code that tries to be Python agnostic, that is, it needs to work both in Python 2 and in Python 3. Otherwise don't, it really makes no difference since Python inserts it for you behind the scenes.

Comment: "depending on the presence or absence of a built-in type as a base-class" => actually it's not about "absence or presence of a builtin type as a base class" but wether the class inherits - directly __or indirectly__ - from `object`. IIRC there was a point in time where not all builtin types where ported to new-style classes yet.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers My impression was that all built-in types did inherit from `object`. I do have a Python 2.2.3 around and after a quick check I couldn't find an offender but, I'll reword the answer later to make it more clear. Would be interested if you could find an example though, my curiosity is piqued.

Comment: In all honesty (cf the "IIRC" in my previous comment) I am not 101% sure about this point (wether all builtin types were already converted to new-style classes when new-style classes were introduced) - I might just be plain wrong, or this might only have concerned some of the standard lib's (but not builtin) types. But yet I think it should be better to clarify that what makes a new-style class is having `object` in it's bases.

Comment: `staticmethod` and `classmethod` work just fine even on old-style classes. `property` sorta works for *reading* on old-style classes, it just fails to intercept writes (so if you assign to the name, the instance gains an attribute of the given name that shadows the property). Also note that `__slots__`'s improvement to attribute access speed is mostly about undoing the loss that new-style class attribute access incurs, so it's not really a selling point of new-style classes (the memory savings are a selling point though).

Comment: Built-in classes (like `str`, `int`, etc) were converted to new-style classes early on, if not immediately. Class defined in pure Python in the standard library, though, were another matter.  (Just to pick a random example, some private helper classes in the `tarfile` module did not explicitly inherit from `object`, even in Python 2.7.)

Comment: Here is an MWE in which `object` is not part of `TestMe.__bases__` in Python 3.x: 
```python
from abc import ABC

class TestMe(ABC): 
    def __init__(self): 
        pass

print(object in TestMe.__bases__)
```
yields `False`....

Answer (score 606):

**Python 3**

- `class MyClass(object):` = New-style class
- `class MyClass:` = New-style class (implicitly inherits from `object`)

**Python 2**

- `class MyClass(object):` = New-style class
- `class MyClass:` = *OLD-STYLE CLASS*

---

**Explanation**:

When defining base classes in Python 3.x, you’re allowed to drop the `object` from the definition. However, this can open the door for a seriously hard to track problem…

Python introduced new-style classes back in Python 2.2, and by now old-style classes are really quite old. Discussion of old-style classes is [buried in the 2.x docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes), and non-existent in the 3.x docs.

The problem is, **the syntax for old-style classes in Python 2.x is the same as the alternative syntax for new-style classes in Python 3.x**. Python 2.x is still very widely used (e.g. GAE, Web2Py), and any code (or coder) unwittingly bringing 3.x-style class definitions into 2.x code is going to end up with some seriously outdated base objects. And because old-style classes aren’t on anyone’s radar, they likely won’t know what hit them.

So just spell it out the long way and save some 2.x developer the tears.

Comment: "When defining base classes in Python 3.x, you’re allowed to drop the object from the definition. However, this can open the door for a seriously hard to track problem…" What problems are you refering to?

Comment: @Aidis: I think they mean that code that runs on both Py2 and Py3 would be fine on Py3, but be broken on Py2 if it relies on new-style class features. Personally, if I'm writing code like that, I omit the explicit inheritance and just put `__metaclass__ = type` at the top of the module (after the `from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function` line :-) ); it's a compatibility hack in Py2 that makes all subsequently defined classes in the module new-style by default, and in Py3, it's completely ignored (just a random global variable sitting around), so it's harmless.

Answer (score 410):

Yes, this is a 'new style' object. It was a feature introduced in python2.2.

New style objects have a different object model to classic objects, and some things won't work properly with old style objects, for instance, `super()`, `@property` and descriptors. See [this article](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/whatsnew/sect-rellinks.html) for a good description of what a new style class is.

SO link for a description of the differences: [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)

Comment: +1 This. Note that old-style classes are gone in Python 3, so you only need to inherit from `object` in Python 2.

Comment: This is not a real answer. ı just gives reference to other articles. I think Yarin's answer should be accepted as the answer to this question.

Comment: @alwbtc : This answer has something new too. For example mention of "super()" led me to another important one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods ).

Answer (score 38):

History from [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex42.html):

> Python's original rendition of a class was broken in many serious
>   ways. By the time this fault was recognized it was already too late,
>   and they had to support it. In order to fix the problem, they needed
>   some "new class" style so that the "old classes" would keep working
>   but you can use the new more correct version.
>
> They decided that they would use a word "object", lowercased, to be
>   the "class" that you inherit from to make a class. It is confusing,
>   but a class inherits from the class named "object" to make a class but
>   it's not an object really its a class, but don't forget to inherit
>   from object.

Also just to let you know what the difference between new-style classes and old-style classes is, it's that new-style classes always inherit from  `object` class or from another class that inherited from `object`:

```
class NewStyle(object):
    pass
```

Another example is:

```
class AnotherExampleOfNewStyle(NewStyle):
    pass
```

While an old-style base class looks like this:

```
class OldStyle():
    pass
```

And an old-style child class looks like this:

```
class OldStyleSubclass(OldStyle):
    pass
```

You can see that an Old Style base class doesn't inherit from any other class, however, Old Style classes can, of course, inherit from one another. Inheriting from object guarantees that certain functionality is available in every Python class. New style classes were introduced in Python 2.2

Comment: Calling the root class `object` isn't all that confusing, and in fact it's pretty standard. Smalltalk has a root class named `Object`, and a root metaclass named `Class`. Why? Because, just as `Dog` is a class for dogs, `Object` is a class for objects, and `Class` is a class for classes. Java, C#, ObjC, Ruby, and most other class-based OO languages that people use today that have a root class use some variation of `Object` as the name, not just Python.

Answer (score 34):

Yes, it's [historical](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/). Without it, it creates an old-style class.

If you use `type()` on an old-style object, you just get "instance". On a new-style object you get its class.

Comment: Also, if you use `type()` on an old-style class, you get "classobj" instead of "type".

Answer (score 9):

The syntax of the class creation statement:

```
class <ClassName>(superclass):
    #code follows
```

In the absence of any other superclasses that you specifically want to inherit from, the `superclass` should always be *`object`*, which is the root of all classes in Python.

*`object`* is technically the root of "new-style" classes in Python. But the new-style classes today are as good as being the only style of classes.

But, if you don't explicitly use the word `object` when creating classes, then as others mentioned, Python 3.x implicitly inherits from the `object` superclass. But I guess explicit is always better than implicit (hell)

[Reference](https://newcircle.com/bookshelf/python_fundamentals_tutorial/oop)