# Why is a good practice to inherit any class we make from the class 'object'?

Tags: python, class

In python, why is recommended to inherit any class we make from the class `object` , why not directly make it as the base class??
An important thing I noticed is that the declaration `__slots__` does not work if I make my class as a base class (instead as a subclass of the class `object`).
What other advantages/disadvantages do I have by inheriting my class from the class `object`?

Comment: This is not quite a duplicate, but please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python .

Comment: possible duplicate of [python class inherits object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object)

Comment: you can find this easily by searching for "python inherit from object"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python2, you must inherit from object in order to create a ["new-style" class](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/). Things like descriptors, `super` and `__slots__` do not work correctly with "old-style" classes, but old-style classes remained for backwards compatibility.

In Python3, all classes are new-style classes, so inheriting from `object` is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

when you inheriting from the object you create new style class, without it you have old style class see: http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/ for more