# Can someone write a simple example of python old style class and new style class?

Tags: python

While there are several articles written about new classes versus old classed I wasn't able to  see a basic example with old/new style.

Comment: Note that old-style classes are gone in Python 3, so you shouldn't care too much. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only syntactic difference is that new style classes inherit from object:

```
class Old:
    ...

class New(object):
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this wiki post](http://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass) is what you are looking for:

```
 <snip> 
 The minor syntactic difference is that New Style Classes happen
 to inherit from object.

 class Old1:
     ...

 class Old2(Old1, UserDict): # Assuming UserDict is still old-style
     ...

 vs

 class New1(object):
     ... class New2(New1):
     ... class New3(Old1, New2):
     ... class New4(dict, Old1):  # dict is a newstyle class
 <snip>
```

Comment: `class New4` is particularly nasty in your example: it is a new style class, but instead of having `object` as the last class in the MRO, the MRO actually goes `New4, dict, object, Old1`.

Comment: @Duncan I can't take credit for that example. It's directly copied from the linked Wiki page. I'll update my post to be clear.