# why object passing is necessry in python with class name

Tags: python

Why object will be passed in certain cases.What is the need passing the object as the class argument.I know that it would be useful at the time of decorators but other than that any other need for this

```
 class MyClass(object):
       def __init__(self):   
          self.numbers = [1,2,3,4,54] 
       def __contains__(self, key):
           return key in self.numbers
```

The second code also works without object argument

```
 class MyClass:
       def __init__(self):   
          self.numbers = [1,2,3,4,54] 
       def __contains__(self, key):
           return key in self.numbers
```

Comment: The parameter passed to the class is the class which it is inheriting from.  I believe it is good practice to always inherit from the base Python object, as your first code example does.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object) asks the same thing.

Comment: The first is called new style class, the second is called old style class. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/q/54867/205528 for the differences

Answer (score 2):

Classes that derive from `object` become [new-style classes](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/).

Comment: note that there's no difference in python3, where all classes are new-style classes

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you are not passing an object as an argument, you are making `MyClass` [*inherit*](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) from the class `object`. The first, inheriting from `object`, is making `MyClass` a [new style class](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/).