# class Classname(object), what sort of word is 'object' in Python?

Tags: python, object, keyword

When I create a module with its sole content:

```
class Classname(randomobject):
    pass
```

And I try to run the .py file of the module the interpreter says that `randomobject` is not defined.

But when I do:

```
class Classname(object):
    pass
```

The module runs just fine. So if `object` is not a keyword, then what is it?

Comment: Here's another question which addresses the Python `object` identifier: [python class inherits object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4015417/404469).

Comment: For the record, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4015417/404469 is not a duplicate. It's about the mechanism of inheritance; this question is about, and has multiple answers about, the syntactic structure of what's going on.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`object` is a (global) variable. By default it is bound to a built-in class which is the root of the type hierarchy.

(This leads to the interesting property that you can take any built-in type, and use the `__bases__` property to reach the type called object).

Everything built-in that isn't a keyword or operator is an identifier.

Comment: Thank you. I assume you can't view the code what is being assigned to this global variable?

Comment: @Bentley4 I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I'm sorry. In /usr/lib/python2.7 you can find the standard python modules. By opening the python files yourself you can see variable assignments,  bodies of the classes and functions etc. of the modules that you can't see by using the help function. Is there any way to access the __builtin__ module and look at the object variable in that module?

Comment: @Bentley4 I've never tried. Consider grepping for it; if not, you'll have to find it in the C source.

Answer (score 18):

The following three class declarations are identical in Python 3

```
class Classname(object):
    pass

class Classname():
    pass

class Classname:
    pass
```

Well, there will be minor [differences](https://python-ast-explorer.com/), but not fundamentally important since the object class is the base for all.

If you plan to write Python agnostic code (Python2 and Python3 agnostic) you may use the first declaration.

Answer (score 8):

`object` is an identifier that refers to a builtin type.

Unlike many other languages, there are no primitive types in Python. Everything is an object, including all data types.

I'm not sure why you expected inheriting from `randomobject` to work.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't entirely clear; I meant that `object` doesn't have special syntactic or semantic significance in Python the way, say, `int` does in Java.

Comment: Strictly, the "type of word that object is" is a variable, for that reason.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 7):

`object` is the base class from which you inherit when creating a new-style class in Python 2.

Comment: It's not necessary to do this in Python 3.x, however. New-style classes are the default.

Comment: In Python 3, all classes still inherit from object. In addition, "the type of word that object is" is an identifier.