# What is object in class Classname(object):?

Tags: python, class, object

[class Classname(object), what sort of word is 'object' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10044533/13595466)

I didn't understand the answers given in the link. What is *object* in `class Classname(object):` in Python?

Comment: The linked answer says it as clearly as I can think of.

Comment: It's the base class of everything, of ever object, that is why it is called `object`. It's a type, just like `list` or `int` or `str`. What is it you don't understand exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `object` is a (global) variable. By default it is bound to a built-in class which is the root of the type hierarchy.
>
> (This leads to the interesting property that you can take any built-in type, and use the `__bases__` property to reach the type called object).
>
> Everything built-in that isn't a keyword or operator is an identifier.

quoting the answere there what it is saying is, `object` is a predefined variable in python self, like open is a predefined function in python.

Comment: What is ```python self```? Moreover, isn't the syntax used for inheriting a class? So, how is ```object``` a variable. If it is predefined, then how to get the list of other predefined variables?