# TypeError: CheckNewsDateStatus() takes no arguments

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I'm trying to update a django/mezzanine application from python 2.7 to python 3.7.  Can you help me in fixing the error below (`CheckNewsDateStatus() takes no arguments`)?

Seems that this class is not used at all; if I grep through all code only the attached settings.py and middleware.py match. Is it something partly implemented in django/mezzanine or it it so that the whole class can be removed as unnecessary ?

I don't know how the code was planned to work and I don't know is the feature has been used at all...

```
(python-3.7) miettinj@ramen:~/pika> python manage.py runserver
BASE_DIR /srv/work/miettinj/pika
PROJECT_ROOT /srv/work/miettinj/pika/pika
/srv/work/miettinj/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/timezone.py:13: PytzUsageWarning: The zone attribute is specific to pytz's interface; please migrate to a new time zone provider. For more details on how to do so, see https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html
  zone_name = tzlocal.get_localzone().zone
/srv/work/miettinj/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/conf.py:67: UserWarning: TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: Europe/Helsinki
  warn("TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: %s" % tz)
BASE_DIR /srv/work/miettinj/pika
PROJECT_ROOT /srv/work/miettinj/pika/pika
/srv/work/miettinj/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/timezone.py:13: PytzUsageWarning: The zone attribute is specific to pytz's interface; please migrate to a new time zone provider. For more details on how to do so, see https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html
  zone_name = tzlocal.get_localzone().zone
/srv/work/miettinj/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/conf.py:67: UserWarning: TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: Europe/Helsinki
  warn("TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: %s" % tz)
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
              .....
          _d^^^^^^^^^b_
       .d''           ``b.
     .p'                `q.
    .d'                   `b.
   .d'                     `b.   * Mezzanine 5.0.0
   ::                       ::   * Django 2.2
  ::    M E Z Z A N I N E    ::  * Python 3.7.10
   ::                       ::   * PostgreSQL 9.3.0
   `p.                     .q'   * Linux 5.3.18-lp152.102-default
    `p.                   .q'
     `b.                 .d'
       `q..          ..p'
          ^q........p^
              ''''

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 30, 2021 - 13:44:54
Django version 2.2, using settings 'pika.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/srv/work/miettinj/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/work/miettinj/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mezzanine/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 170, in inner_run
    super().inner_run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/work/miettinj/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 137, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/srv/work/miettinj/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mezzanine/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 173, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/srv/work/miettinj/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/srv/work/miettinj/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 64, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "/srv/work/miettinj/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 42, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return get_wsgi_application()
  File "/srv/work/miettinj/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/srv/work/miettinj/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/srv/work/miettinj/python-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 37, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: CheckNewsDateStatus() takes no arguments
```

middlewary.py:

```
class CheckNewsDateStatus(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if '/uutinen/' in request.path:
            try:
                path_to_go_raw = request.path
                true_slug = path_to_go_raw.split('/uutinen/')[1:]
                news_obj = Uutinen.objects.get(slug=true_slug[0])
                now_utc = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.now())
                
                hel = pytz.timezone("Europe/Helsinki")
                foo = news_obj.publish_date.astimezone(hel)
                
                if foo.date() < now_utc.date() and news_obj.status == 2:
                    pass
                elif foo.date() == now_utc.date() and foo.time() < now_utc.time()  and news_obj.status == 2:
                    pass
                else:
                    if request.user.is_authenticated():
                        pass
                    elif news_obj.status == 1:
                        return HttpResponseNotFound('404')
                    else:
                        return HttpResponseNotFound('404')
            except:
                pass
```

settings.py:

```
# List of middleware classes to use. Order is important; in the request phase,
# these middleware classes will be applied in the order given, and in the
# response phase the middleware will be applied in reverse order.
MIDDLEWARE = (
    'page_types.middleware.SetDynamicSite',
#    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.UpdateCacheMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    #"django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "statfi_search.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.request.CurrentRequestMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForDeviceMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForHostMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.AdminLoginInterfaceSelectorMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.SitePermissionMiddleware",
    # Uncomment the following if using any of the SSL settings:
    # "mezzanine.core.middleware.SSLRedirectMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
    'page_types.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
    'page_types.middleware.CheckNewsDateStatus',
)
```

Comment: classes are simply defined as `class CheckNewsDateStatus:` in Python3. there is no need to explicitly write `(object)` as the argument to your class anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [class Classname(object), what sort of word is 'object' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044321/class-classnameobject-what-sort-of-word-is-object-in-python)

Comment: @Ankit Tiwari I made the change, but I still get the same error. Don't understand. According to python3 documentation you should be correct

Comment: Hello @Jaana can you provide directory structure of your middleware

Comment: Did this answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322262/how-to-set-up-custom-middleware-in-django

Comment: @Ankit Tiwari yes, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Django 2.2, your Middleware class must accept a get_response argument:

you should define your class like this.

```
class CheckNewsDateStatus(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response 

    def process_request(self, request):
        ....
```

Also, there is no need to write (object) while defining your class in Python3+.

For your reference, [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware).