# Class definitions deriving from object

Tags: python, oop, class, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Old style and new style classes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)
>   [python class inherits object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object)

What's the difference between

```
class foo:
```

and

```
class foo(object):
```

Can anyone explain why we are using object in class definition?

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x the first declaration is an old-style class and the second version is a new-style class. You should always use new-style classes for new code.

In Python 3 all classes are new-style so there is no difference.