# assigning variable to object python

Tags: python, object, python-2.7

Does the `object` keyword have any uses except for classes like:

```
class HelloWorld(object):
    pass
```

Because when assigning a variable to `object` it seems as if there is no use for it (no `variable.__dict__` or anything).

for example:

```
x=object()
x.anything="foo"#<----- throws an error
```

Comment: Just to clarify, its not a keyword, but a base class - almost like an interface, that all objects implicitly inherit from.

Comment: Explained here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible use is for sentinel values - things that you want to have unique values that can't be duplicated by accident. For instance:

```
NOT_SET = object()

def some_function(arg=NOT_SET):
    if arg is NOT_SET:
        # the user didn't pass in a value for 'arg'
     else:
        # the user passed in a value for 'arg'
```

Because every object instance has a unique identity, the `if` statement's condition will only be true if the user didn't pass in a value (unlike the common default value for a parameter, `None`, which the user might pass in to some functions).