# What does the object in python class header do?

Tags: python, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python class inherits object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object)

In Python 2.7, what is the difference between:

```
class MyClass(Object):
```

and

```
class MyClass:
```

What does the Object do?

Comment: Is `Object` really capitalized in the place you've seen that sort of code? (If so, it's really bad style, since it can be mistaken for the built in `object` class.) As the answer to the question @jozzas linked says, inheriting (directly or indirectly) from `object` is necessary in Python 2 to get a "new-style" class, rather than a deprecated "old-style" class.

Comment: It was. But in my IDE it prefers object instead of Object. Compared to other languages, the object class is usually capitalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Object` in this case the base class of `MyClass`, meaning that it 'inherits' the methods and variables of `Object` unless overwritten. Inheriting from `object`, however, creates a 'new-style class' as opposed to an 'old-style class'. For more information, see [jozzas' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207656/what-does-the-object-in-python-class-header-do#comment19701676_14207656)

See [this tutorial](http://docspy2zh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) for information about inheritance.

Comment: So its for inheritance. I'm used to Class (): <inheritclass> Thanks!.

Comment: This is a special circumstance, as *not* inheriting from `Object` gives you an "old-style" class in Python 2.7. See the question I linked in my other comment.

Comment: SO says I can't accept for another 8 minutes. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: Inheriting from something named `Object` is not the same as from `object`...