# python: set read-only attribute for class objects

Tags: python

I've created a class object called 'Node'. I then created two subclasses 'Beetle' and 'Dakota'. You'll notice there is an attr called 'superclass' which is part of the baseclass. I want this attribute to be set for each subclass and once it's set it should never be changed. It's a read-only attribute. I was wondering how to set this attribute up correctly in order to be a read only attribute?

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, superclass, attributes, children):
        self.name = name
        self.superclass = superclass
        self.attributes = attributes if attributes is not None else {}
        self.children = children if children is not None else []


    class Beetle(Node):
        def __init__(self, name="", superclass="Cars", attributes=None, children=None, enabled=True):
            super(Beetle, self).__init__(name=name, superclass=superclass, attributes=attributes, children=children)
            self.enabled = enabled


    class Dakota(Node):
        def __init__(self, name="", superclass="Trucks", attributes=None, children=None, enabled=True):
            super(Dakota, self).__init__(name=name, superclass=superclass, attributes=attributes, children=children)
            self.enabled = enabled
```

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594120/python-read-only-property) seem relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename you variable to add `__` to the begining

```
self.__superclass = superclass
```

you can't access `self.__superclass` with something like `Dakota().__superclass`

if you want to get value of `__superclass` add a function in `Node` class to return it.

```
def getsuperclass(self):
    return self.__superclass
...

Dakota().getsuperclass()
```

Comment: what if i prefixed it with just a single _ would i then be able to get it by 

Dakota()._superclass

Comment: Yes.it will possible to get it by `Dakota()._superclass`.

Answer (score 2):

To have a 'read-only' property in a class you can make use of the @property decoration.

An example:

```
class Dakota(object):
def __init__(self, superclass):
    self.__superclass = superclass

    @property
    def superclass(self):
        return self.__superclass
```

Usage:

```
>>> a = Dakota('lol')
>>> a.superclass
'lol'
>>> a.superclass = 'hah'
AttributeError...    

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

You can refer to this other [answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594120/python-read-only-property)

Comment: 2 ways to set the attribute: 1 (set the attribute) `a._Dakota__superclass = None`; 2 (add a setter to `Dakota.superclass.fset`) `Dakota.superclass.__init__( Dakota.superclass.fget, lambda self,value: setattr(self,'_%s__superclass'%(self.__class__.__name__),value) )` (it's funny how `slice()` has more security than `property()` haha)