# Ensure uniqueness of instance attribute in python

Tags: python, oop

I have written a class with an instance attribute, call it name. What is the best way of ensuring that all instances of the class will have unique names? Do I create under the class, a set and every time a new instance is created, the name gets added to the set in the definition of init? Since a set is a collection of unique elements, I can therefore validate against whether the new instance's name can be successfully added to the set.

EDIT: I wanted to be able to supply the name instead of assigning a UUID to it. So mementum's approach seems the most robust. jpkotta's is what I would have done.

Comment: This sounds like something better enforced at a different level, if at all. If you enforce it like this, you'll eventually find that "wait, I only want names to be unique across [certain data structures/logical divisions of the program]", or "wait, I deleted the old object with this name, why can't I reuse the name now?"

Comment: Are you going to be persisting these anywhere?

Comment: Following your edit I added a combination of the `metaclass` and `descriptor` approaches which tries to use the best of both worlds. In my own projects my `metaclasses` do even remove parameters before they touch `__init__`, to alleviate the need for end users to cope with those parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control instance creation with metaclasses (for example) and ensure that the name is unique. Let's assume that the `__init__` method takes a parameter `name` which has no default value

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
```

Obviously, instances can have the same name with this. Let's use a `metaclass` (using compatible Python 2/3 syntax)

```
class MyMeta(type):
    _names = set()

    @classmethod
    def as_metaclass(meta, *bases):
        '''Create a base class with "this metaclass" as metaclass

        Meant to be used in the definition of classes for Py2/3 syntax equality

        Args:
          bases: a list of base classes to apply (object if none given)
        '''
        class metaclass(meta):
            def __new__(cls, name, this_bases, d):
                # subclass to ensure super works with our methods
                return meta(name, bases, d)
        return type.__new__(metaclass, str('tmpcls'), (), {})

    def __call__(cls, name, *args, **kwargs):
        if name in cls._names:
            raise AttributeError('Duplicate Name')

        cls._names.add(name)
        return type.__call__(cls, name, *args, **kwargs)


class MyClass(MyMeta.as_metaclass()):
    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = name


a = MyClass('hello')
print('a.name:', a.name)
b = MyClass('goodbye')
print('b.name:', b.name)

try:
    c = MyClass('hello')
except AttributeError:
    print('Duplicate Name caught')
else:
    print('c.name:', c.name)
```

Which outputs:

```
a.name: hello
b.name: goodbye
Duplicate Name caught
```

Using the `metaclass` technique you could even avoid having `name` as a parameter and the names could be generated automatically for each instance.

```
import itertools

class MyMeta(type):
    _counter = itertools.count()

    @classmethod
    def as_metaclass(meta, *bases):
        '''Create a base class with "this metaclass" as metaclass

        Meant to be used in the definition of classes for Py2/3 syntax equality

        Args:
          bases: a list of base classes to apply (object if none given)
        '''
        class metaclass(meta):
            def __new__(cls, name, this_bases, d):
                # subclass to ensure super works with our methods
                return meta(name, bases, d)
        return type.__new__(metaclass, str('tmpcls'), (), {})

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        obj.name = '%s_%d' % (cls.__name__, next(cls._counter))
        return obj


class MyClass(MyMeta.as_metaclass()):
    pass


a = MyClass()
print('a.name:', a.name)

b = MyClass()
print('b.name:', b.name)

c = MyClass()
print('c.name:', c.name)
```

Output:

```
a.name: MyClass_0
b.name: MyClass_1
c.name: MyClass_2
```

To complete the question and answering the comment about preventing `a.name = b.name` (or any other name already in use) one can use a `descriptor` based approach

```
class DescName(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = {None: self}

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        return self.cache[obj]

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        cls = obj.__class__

        if value in cls._names:
            raise AttributeError('EXISTING NAME %s' % value)

        try:
            cls._names.remove(self.cache[obj])
        except KeyError:  # 1st time name is used
            pass
        cls._names.add(value)
        self.cache[obj] = value


class MyClass(object):
    _names = set()

    name = DescName()

    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = name


a = MyClass('hello')
print('a.name:', a.name)
b = MyClass('goodbye')
print('b.name:', b.name)

try:
    c = MyClass('hello')
except AttributeError:
    print('Duplicate Name caught')
else:
    print('c.name:', c.name)

a.name = 'see you again'
print('a.name:', a.name)

try:
    a.name = b.name
except AttributeError:
    print('CANNOT SET a.name to b.name')
else:
    print('a.name %s = %s b.name' % (a.name, b.name))
```

With the expected output (names cannot be reused during `__init__` or assignment)

```
a.name: hello
b.name: goodbye
Duplicate Name caught
a.name: see you again
CANNOT SET a.name to b.name
```

EDIT:

Since the OP favours this approach, a combined `metaclass` and `descriptor` approach which covers:

- `name` class attribute as `descriptor`added by the `metaclass` during class creation
- `name` per instance initialization before the instance gets to `__init__`
- `name` uniqueness also for assignment operations
- storing the `set` and `itertools.counter` controlling name uniqueness inside the `descriptor` class which removes pollution from the class itself

```py
import itertools


class MyMeta(type):
    class DescName(object):
        def __init__(self, cls):
            self.cache = {None: self, cls: set()}
            self.counter = {cls: itertools.count()}

        def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
            return self.cache[obj]

        def __set__(self, obj, value):
            self.setname(obj, value)

        def setname(self, obj, name=None):
            cls = obj.__class__
            name = name or '%s_%d' % (cls.__name__, next(self.counter[cls]))

            s = self.cache[cls]
            if name in s:
                raise AttributeError('EXISTING NAME %s' % name)

            s.discard(self.cache.get(obj, None))
            s.add(name)
            self.cache[obj] = name

    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        cls = super(MyMeta, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)
        cls.name = meta.DescName(cls)  # add the name class attribute
        return cls

    @classmethod
    def as_metaclass(meta, *bases):
        class metaclass(meta):
            def __new__(cls, name, this_bases, d):
                # subclass to ensure super works with our methods
                return meta(name, bases, d)
        return type.__new__(metaclass, str('tmpcls'), (), {})

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # Instead of relying on type we do the new and init calls
        obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        cls.name.setname(obj)
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj


class MyClass(MyMeta.as_metaclass()):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__init__ with name:', self.name)


a = MyClass()
b = MyClass()
c = MyClass()

a.name = 'my new name'
print('a.name:', a.name)

try:
    a.name = b.name
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)
else:
    print('a.name %s == %s b.name' % (a.name, b.name))
```

Which outputs the expected:

```
__init__ with name: MyClass_0
__init__ with name: MyClass_1
__init__ with name: MyClass_2
a.name: my new name
EXISTING NAME MyClass_1
```

Comment: TLDR - does it prevent `b.name = a.name`?

Comment: The OP wanted to control creation ... not modification. So no, it does not. You need to (or can) use a `descriptor` to control that

Comment: Added a `descriptor` based approach

Comment: the OP said `What is the best way of ensuring that all instances of the class will have unique names?`..

Comment: Yes and he goes and elaborates about "instance creation". But the point was already taken and the answer extended. Better long than short and hopefully it helps the OP. He may even combine both techniques

Comment: nope, long is NOT better for all people, I am myself completely lost in this answer. and let's not confuse **problem statement** with **solution suggestion**

Answer (score 3):

```
class Foo():
    _names = set()

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def __init__(self, name):
        if name in Foo._names:
            raise NameError("Already used name '%s'." % name)

        self._name = name
        Foo._names.add(name)
```

To me, this is simpler than messing with metaclasses, etc.  If you need to do this for several classes, metaclasses make more sense.

Making name a property without a write method makes assignment fail, effectively making `name` constant.

If you subclass `Foo`, it keeps the same set of names across all subclasses, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from uuid import uuid4
>>> 
>>> class class_with_unique_name(object):
...     def __init__(self): 
...         self.name = str(uuid4())
...         
... 
>>> class_with_unique_name().name
'e2ce6b4e-8989-4390-b044-beb71d834385'
>>> class_with_unique_name().name
'ff277b1b-b149-47f6-9dc9-f9faecd18d11'
>>> class_with_unique_name().name
'63f70cbc-4f0a-4c8b-a35f-114bc5b8bc8d'
>>> class_with_unique_name().name
'a6f95523-ae43-4900-9366-022326474210'
>>> class_with_unique_name().name
'4e7c1200-bd45-427e-bcf0-e643b41f6347'
>>> class_with_unique_name().name
'58fa246e-4f99-49d4-9420-68234e24c921'
>>> class_with_unique_name().name
'7c86b351-fdb9-40c1-8021-b93c70e8e24d'
```

Comment: While this would certainly ensure uniqueness it may not be what the OP wants. It sounds like they want to be able to declare `name` at instantiation. More clarification is needed.

Comment: it solves this problem statement perfectly: "I have written a class with an instance attribute, call it name. What is the best way of ensuring that all instances of the class will have unique names?"

Comment: agree this is part of the the *best way* to do what OP said - `self.name` should be uneditable though.. no ambiguities in the requirements as stated. possibility of declaring custom `name`s is incompatible with ensuring the uniqueness since there is nothing said what should happen when attempting to declare the same name again or changing an existing name

Comment: @rbp Unless the way OP intends to use the class is `obj = MyClass(name=some_input_from_a_form)`. If the OP intends to use the class like so `obj = MyClass()` this approach would be great. Unless the OP was going to persist them in a DB then the best method would be to let the DB enforce uniqueness. We need further clarification before deciding the "best" way.

Comment: @Aprillion it would be fairly easy to make `name` a property, with no setter.

Comment: so what's stopping you?

Comment: its not in the OP's problem statement.  here are instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594120/python-read-only-property