# Why do Python programmers not use properties very often?

Tags: python, properties

I am using both Python and C#.

In C# it is almost required to use properties. 
In Python it is possible to use properties, but I do not see them in use very often.

Is there a specific reason why Pythonistas to not use properties as much as programmers of other languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Python's philosophy

> Python is a language for consenting adults.
>   — [Alan Runyan](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/fluent-python/9781491946237/pr03.html) Cofounder of Plone

In Python the philosophy is that we're all [responsible users](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#we-are-all-responsible-users) (maybe an improvement on the term ["consenting adults"](https://github.com/kennethreitz/python-guide/pull/524/files)), so we do not protect data unless there we believe there to be a benefit for the user.

Cultural evidence:

- [Python read-only property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594120/python-read-only-property)
- Tutor mailing list, 2003: [What is Pythonic](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html)

## Reasons we might use properties:

- Maybe the attribute is something that can be calculated and is not needed often, thus saving space.
- Maybe the attribute is required to be a specific type that could easily be given the wrong type or value by a user, and so you can create value for the user by managing the access to it.
- Maybe the attribute would be better as a function, but it started out as a simple dotted lookup but then grew into one of the two above, so we keep the API to avoid breaking users.

## Reasons we might not use properties:

- Maybe the code is only going to be used by the author, making it less important to protect the users.
- Maybe we are trying to coax more performance from the code by precalculating attributes, and don't mind the memory tradeoffs.
- Maybe we want our code to be more terse/less verbose.

## It's a matter of judgment

Note that the reasons given are matters of the programmer's judgment. Managed properties are not required by the language, but they are a feature. If you think your users don't need them, you can avoid paying the computational costs to do so.

## Conclusion

Other languages do not necessarily share this philosophy - instead the culture is that you must write code that you will only use yourself as if you are a community of users. That is why they will have more use of these kinds of data-hiding than you typically see in Python code.