# attribute error, singleton pattern with property method

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

While handling the database connection I used the singleton pattern for the evident reason. for simplification purposes, I have simplified the class definition, the problem is still the same.

the class:

```
class Point(object):
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, x, y):
        if Point._instance is None:
            Point._instance = object.__new__(cls)
            Point._instance.x = x
            Point._instance.y = y
        return Point._instance

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self._x = self._instance.x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, y):
        self._y = self._instance.y

    def __str__(self):
        return 'x: {}, y: {} id.x: {}'.format(self.x, self.y, id(self.x))
```

it generates the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute '_x'
```

I have found the following workaround:

```
class Point(object):
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, x, y):
        if Point._instance is None:
            Point._instance = object.__new__(cls)
            Point._instance.x = x
            Point._instance.y = y
        return Point._instance

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = self._instance.x
        self.y = self._instance.y
```

The pythonic way is to use property method, hence I still have that itch, even though I have a working code, can someone explain to me why-why I have such an error.

Comment: The indentation. It hurts.

Comment: Why would you want a Point class to be a singleton?!

Comment: @jq170727 I didn't pay attention to the indentation sorry, I just past code from my editor.

Comment: @wim Point class is beside the point, rather than posting all the code that handles the connection to the database and losing the point, i duplicated the same error on something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking `self.x` in your `__init__`, control (via the descriptor) is moves to the setter for `x` which does:

```
self._x = self._instance.x
```

which, in turn, invokes the getter which tries to do:

```
return self._x
```

before `self._x` has been set. A similar situation exists for `_y`.

I'm under the impression you don't want people altering the values for `x` and `y`, if that is the case, make them [read-only properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594120/python-read-only-property).

As an addendum, there's no reason to set the values `x` and `y` in `__new__`, you set them in `__init__`.

Comment: as mentioned in my question, the original class is for handling database connection, hence I prevent multiple instantiations, and please bear with me and imagine x as the connection and y as the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure I understand why you would want to do this, you could try:

```python
_instance = None

def Point(x,y):
    class _Point(object):
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
        def __str__(self):
            return 'x: {}, y: {} id.x: {}'.format(self.x, self.y, id(self.x))
    global _instance
    if _instance is None:
        _instance = _Point(x,y)
    return _instance    

p1 = Point(1,2)
print "p1", p1

p2 = Point(3,4)
p2.x = 10
print "p2", p2

print "p1", p1
```

Output

```python
p1 x: 1, y: 2 id.x: 94912852734312
p2 x: 10, y: 2 id.x: 94912852734096
p1 x: 10, y: 2 id.x: 94912852734096
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDBisMgFLz7FY9emoCE6vZU2F8o/QNJU7NryaqoBaXst2efJiQhOxd1ZpzRZ1P4NpqPo1Dah1Z3Ej7harQk5CF7uBmlQxVpqi8EEN3Qeg9ios39KbswKxn5hsAgFYSovBx6CpFC2jgystBErIn/6YR02uX54Oa4XZCT4eU0HOMF3r/YkxdQj6acj01v3E8bqqmOzvkUDTNV1yXtazD3doDl/4VU/UqA8mUia/l2VmIdEdk8arUgCLEMrZOTUV4T63ALB8sOFCxDnS/6Bz2jzsuE2Glx8uzkZHdzHP8A)