# python property decorator in OOP

Tags: python, decorator

I was testing the idea of using `@property` in OOP:

```
class Person(object):
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, newname):
        self.name = newname

james = Person()
james.name = 'James Bond'
print(james.name)
>>> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Somehow this gives me an Error for recursion??

but if I change `self.name` to `self._name`, it seems to solve the problem. So I guess I can not set a `self.name` while I am using `name()` as a `@property`?

Comment: The whole point of the descriptor protocol is that `obj.x` calls `x.__get__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you are attempting to return an attribute with exactly the same name as the method being decorated by `property`. Thus, when you call the method `name`, the call triggers the method again, because `self.name` is the method declared in the class. This triggers the non-terminating recursion. Instead, change the attribute name:

```
class Person(object):
   @property
   def name(self):
     return self._name

   @name.setter
   def name(self, newname):
      self._name = newname
```

Comment: So the way I found, which is to add `'_'`, is a proper way to do this?

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 in this case, all you need to do is change the variable name. Generally, `_variablename` is used in most demonstrations of `property`.

Comment: Another way is to use `self.__dict__['name']`, which is a little more arcane but a very cool way to hide property values.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can create the internal proxy object if you think that _ notation is ugly (example for python 3.3+):

```
import types

class Person(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.me = types.SimpleNamespace(name = "")

   @property
   def name(self):
     return self.me.name

   @name.setter
   def name(self, newname):
      self.me.name = newname
```

Comment: You don't really eliminate what to me is the main ugliness of `_`, which is that you create another attribute for the user to modify.

Comment: Maybe little magic with class decorator will protect the variable against overriding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39716001/4265407 but not from field access and manipulation. I think we need something like `inspect` to do it.

Comment: As I suggested for the other answer, `self.__dict__['name']` goes a long way to hiding the attribute by harnessing the precedence of data attributes on the class over instance dict entries.

Comment: But if I wrote `s.__dict__['name'] = "foo"` I can write `s.name = "bar"` after. Given the fact that many critical variables usually defined/assigned in the class constructor...