# Constant python class

Tags: python

I want to create python class with read only properties.

Please see this example:

```
class ClassProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, getter):
        self.getter = getter

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.getter(owner)


class Constants(object):
    @ClassProperty
    def version(cls):
        return '1.0.11'
```

So under this `(cls)` word i have this message:

```
Usually first parameter of method is named self
```

So i wonder is i need to declare it this way:

```
class Constants(object):
    @ClassProperty
    def version(self):
        return '1.0.11'
```

And in this way the message disappear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python read-only property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594120/python-read-only-property)

Comment: `cls` is normally only used in metaclass methods. Ordinary class methods use `self`. These are just naming conventions, you're not even using the parameter, so it doesn't really matter. But your IDE is helping you follow normal practices.

Comment: The message is just a hint, it doesn't affect how the methods work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a read-only class property in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203286/how-to-create-a-read-only-class-property-in-python/26634248)

Comment: @LogicalBranch What do any of those questions have to do with the message "Usually first parameter of method is named self"?

Comment: So this is ok to change it to self ?

Comment: You can call it whatever you want. It's not being used, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Function parameters can be named anything, they don't have any special meaning. LIke I said, it's just a convention.