# Prevent mutation of property in specific subclass

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I have a superclass where one property is an enumeration.

There are some specific subclasses that inherit from this class where only one case of the enumeration makes sense, so ideally I would like to prevent it being changed in these subclasses.

Here is a minimal example using medical professionals:

```
from enum import Enum, unique, auto

# My enum for medical specialities
@unique
class Speciality (Enum):
    Anaesthetics = auto()
    Dermatology = auto()
    General_Practice = auto()
    Surgery = auto()

# My superclass
class Doctor:
    speciality = Specialty # Could be any case

# An example subclass
class GP (Doctor):
    speciality = Specialty.GeneralPractice # Must be General Practice
```

Is there a way to make the `speciality` property immutable in the GP subclass? If not, is there a way to implement similar functionality?

Comment: Have you looked at [@property and @setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/using-property-versus-getters-and-setters)? If you want a setter to fail (i.e. a read-only property), raise an exception?

Comment: @Jens Thanks for your response. No I’m not familiar with those. Could that also prevent mutation at any point after initialisation?

Comment: Yes, the point of these is to have more controlled access to object properties.

Comment: @Jens eh, no, there are several built-in immutable types. `str`, `tuple`, `bytes`, `frozenset` ... but you are correct, user-defined types are pretty much always mutable, but you can add some things to prevent accidental mutation

Comment: Looking at your example though, it looks to me like the `specialty` is redundant: it is encoded in the class, no? I mean, the class `GP` has the `GeneralPracticioner` specialty. If that’s what you’re after, consider removing the `specialty` property and instead use [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) or [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).

Comment: @Jens That’s what I thought about mutability in Python. Yes in this case the class name implies the speciality, so `type()` would be a possibility, but I have other classes (e.g. Surgeon) and so it would be convenient to have an instance of specialty for each. They will have a speciality property anyway due to inheritance, so I am also trying to guard against it changing. I will consider your `type()` idea though - might just need a small refactor of the class structures.

Comment: @Jens How might I use `@property` and `@setter`?

Comment: Also, it might be interesting to poke around this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594120/python-read-only-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the initial conversation and using [property decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/using-property-versus-getters-and-setters), this should work:

```
>>> from abc import ABC
>>> class Doctor(ABC):
...     """Abstract Base Class for doctors."""
...     pass
... 
>>> class GP(Doctor):
...     @property
...     def specialty(self):
...         return Specialty.GeneralPractice
...     @specialty.setter
...     def specialty(self, value):
...         raise ValueError("Unable to modify a Doctor's specialty")
```

which then allows you to read, but not write the `specialty` property:

```
>>> gp = GP()
>>> gp.specialty
<Speciality.General_Practice: 3>
>>> gp.specialty = Speciality.Dermatology
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in specialty
ValueError: Unable to modify a Doctor's specialty
```

Further reading: [Property](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) and [Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html).

Comment: Thanks for this and the links - I’ll do some reading and experimentation for a bit.

Comment: @Chris the above is not an ideal solution because you’d replicate the setter & property use across classes. I would probably aim at using ABC and make more use of the dynamic [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Comment: I’m still getting my head around abstract base classes, but the decorator solution works great as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris great! On second thought, I would be tempted to raise [`AttributeError`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/exceptions.html#AttributeError) instead of [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/exceptions.html#ValueError), just to be more precise with Python’s error semantics.

Comment: Thanks. I was just reading on the link you shared that not having a corresponding setter will raise an Attribute Error anyway if you try to set the variable. I guess it makes more sense to use the same in a custom implementation.