# Python, creating objects

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python and I now I am trying to get the hang of classes and how to manipulate them with instances.

I can't seem to understand this practice problem:

Create and return a student object whose name, age, and major are
the same as those given as input

```
def make_student(name, age, major)
```

I just don't get what it means by object, do they mean I should create an array inside the function that holds these values? or create a class and let this function be inside it, and assign instances? (before this question i was asked to set up a student class with name, age, and major inside)

```
class Student:
    name = "Unknown name"
    age = 0
    major = "Unknown major"
```

Comment: Read the data model docs, specifically the `__init__` method is relevant here:   http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__

Comment: None (no quotes) is the common *unassigned* default value in python

Answer (score 192, accepted):

```
class Student(object):
    name = ""
    age = 0
    major = ""

    # The class "constructor" - It's actually an initializer 
    def __init__(self, name, age, major):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.major = major

def make_student(name, age, major):
    student = Student(name, age, major)
    return student
```

Note that even though one of the principles in Python's philosophy is *"there should be one—and preferably only one—obvious way to do it"*, there are still multiple ways to do this. You can also use the two following snippets of code to take advantage of Python's dynamic capabilities:

```
class Student(object):
    name = ""
    age = 0
    major = ""

def make_student(name, age, major):
    student = Student()
    student.name = name
    student.age = age
    student.major = major
    # Note: I didn't need to create a variable in the class definition before doing this.
    student.gpa = float(4.0)
    return student
```

I prefer the former, but there are instances where the latter can be useful – one being when working with document databases like MongoDB.

Comment: why are you initializing them as class variables prior to your init? (curious; haven't seen that pattern very often)

Comment: For readability purposes. By putting the class variables near the top prior to the init, I can quickly see which variables are in the class scope since they might not all be set by the constructor.

Comment: Here the name of the object which is the instance of the class Student is going to remain student right? What if I want multiple objects at each call with the name student01, student02,.. and so on?

Comment: Creating class variables to see what your instance variables is terrible practice.  To any novice readers: look at @pyrospade's answer instead.

Comment: Your example is misleading. Please use class variable names which are in reality a property of all students, rather than misusing a property of each student. For example: use `class Unicorn` and `has_hooves = True` instead of `name = ""`.

Answer (score 59):

Create a class and give it an `__init__` method:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, major):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.major = major

    def is_old(self):
        return self.age > 100
```

Now, you can initialize an instance of the `Student` class:

```
>>> s = Student('John', 88, None)
>>> s.name
    'John'
>>> s.age
    88
```

Although I'm not sure why you need a `make_student` student function if it does the same thing as `Student.__init__`.

Comment: Our teacher gave us a test.py program that tests if we did the problems correctly. The question wants me to specifically to use the make_student function. The end goal is to:
    s1 = make_student(name, age, major) 
and now I have everything assigned to s1. But again I'm not sure what they want s1 to be? I can do this with an array {'name' : name..etc} but that didn't give me a correct answer so I'm assuming I need to implement what I learned from classes and instances

Comment: The so called "factory method" pattern, the one where you use a method or a function to create object of some kind instead of creating them directly in the code, is a useful pattern, it allows you to exploit nice things about inheritance for example. Look it up ;)

Answer (score 34):

Objects are instances of classes.  Classes are just the blueprints for objects.  So given your class definition -

```
# Note the added (object) - this is the preferred way of creating new classes
class Student(object):
    name = "Unknown name"
    age = 0
    major = "Unknown major"
```

You can create a `make_student` function by explicitly assigning the attributes to a new instance of `Student` -

```
def make_student(name, age, major):
    student = Student()
    student.name = name
    student.age = age
    student.major = major
    return student
```

But it probably makes more sense to do this in a constructor (`__init__`) -

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name="Unknown name", age=0, major="Unknown major"):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.major = major
```

The constructor is called when you use `Student()`.  It will take the arguments defined in the `__init__` method.  The constructor signature would now essentially be `Student(name, age, major)`.

If you use that, then a `make_student` function is trivial (and superfluous) -

```
def make_student(name, age, major):
    return Student(name, age, major)
```

For fun, here is an example of how to create a `make_student` function without defining a class.  Please do not try this at home.

```
def make_student(name, age, major):
    return type('Student', (object,),
                {'name': name, 'age': age, 'major': major})()
```

Comment: Actually, I prefer not to do class Name(object): for verbosity reasons. The Python documentation tends to not do it as well. I like the "dangerous" example of feeding in a dict though.  http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: I withdraw my previous comment. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object. So there is actually a reason to spell out class Name(object):

Comment: There is no constructor in python :)

Comment: How is the `__init__()` method different from a constructor?

Comment: `__init__` is not a constructor, "because the object has already been constructed by the time `__init__` is called, and you already have a valid reference to the new instance of the class." (http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html)

Comment: I guess that is technically correct since `__new__` is the real constructor; however, `__init__` is used analogously as constructors are used in other languages (e.g. C++, Java).

Comment: what's the purpose of putting 'object' when creating a new class?

Comment: To create a new-style class - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374857/should-all-python-classes-extend-object

Answer (score 3):

when you create an object using predefine class, at first you want to create a variable for storing that object. Then you can create object and store variable that you created.

```
class Student:
     def __init__(self):

# creating an object....

   student1=Student()
```

Actually this **init** method is the constructor of class.you can initialize that method using some attributes.. In that point , when you creating an object , you will have to pass some values for particular attributes..

```
class Student:
      def __init__(self,name,age):
            self.name=value
            self.age=value

 # creating an object.......

     student2=Student("smith",25)
```