# Python: How to make the the value of a variable an object

Tags: python, class, variables

I am currently trying to create a program in python that randomly creates an object in a class when run. However, the problem I've run into is that when i attempt to create the object with code like this:

```
name = sword(name, rarity, dam)
```

I get an object with the reference being the variable name and not the actual name stored inside. How do create the object using the value inside the name variable as the reference?

Comment: Have you tried binding it to a different name?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You assign the result to `name`. Assign it to something else.

Comment: I would like to assign the result to the value stored inside the variable name. is that possible?

Comment: Try This Code out This might be what you are looking for  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081542/python-creating-objects>