# Is there a way to make a function where you can call it like a python method?

Tags: python, function, methods

Is there a way to make a python function so that you can call it like a method? So say i had variable `x`, and I had a function:

```
def func(y):
     return str(y)+"hi"
```

Then call it like `x.func()` and have it take x in as the input?

Comment: Define it in the class that's the type of `x`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, creating objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081542/python-creating-objects)