# what does python class take in arguments

Tags: python, inheritance

I am confused on what the folowing means:

```
class class_name(object):
```

What does the class takes in between the parenthesis? is it inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

It's the superclass. There can be more than one, though getting that right and making it useful can be a bit tricky. There can also be none, but unless you're on Python 3, that's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is inheritance. You might find this thread and some of the related links useful: [Python class inherits object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's inheritance. This is what it looks like:

```
class DerivedClass(BaseClass)
```

In your declaration, you're basically inheriting the `object` type. It's a built-in. However, in Python 3 you don't need to do this, as every class is implicitly a subclass of `object`.

By the way, more about this [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

```
class class_name(object):
```

This is called inheritance
Python also supports multiple inheritance , that means you can inherit from multiple classes
for example:
`class class_name(BaseClassName1,BaseClassName2,BaseClassName3):`