# what is diff between both of class definition

Tags: python, class, inheritance

In Python 2, classes should explicitly be defined as subclasses of object. In Python 3, this will be the
default.

```
>>> class A(object):
    pass

>>> class B():
    pass

>>> type(B)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> type(A)
<type 'type'>
```

I use Python 2.7 and as I know in 2.7 `class` inherits from `object`.

Comment: read this for an explanation of new style classes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `class` inherits from `object` in python >=3.0, but not 2.7.  You still have to explicitly inherit from `object` in python 2.x.

Answer (score 4):

That is a so-called "new style object", introduced in python 2.2.

New style objects have a different object model to classic objects, and some things won't work properly with old style objects, for instance, super(), @property and descriptors.

More on it in the famous question:

- [Python class inherits object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object)

Please also refer to:

- https://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/whatsnew/sect-rellinks.html

Also,  please note that there is a difference between them only in Python 2. In Python 3 you have no difference between these two types of declaration anymore (I know that your question is about Python 2, just a small note).

Comment: Which one is the new style object?

Comment: @omeinusch: The first one, `A`