# What is object() good for?

Tags: python, class, object

How is it possible that

```
class EmptyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

e = EmptyClass()
e.a = 123
```

works and:

```
o = object()
o.a = 123
```

does not (`AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'a'`) while

```
print isinstance(e, object)
>>> True
```

?

What is `object()` good for then, when you cannot use it like this?

Comment: Simply because everything is a object. So for anything to exist, `object` must exist too.

Comment: Maybe [this question and it's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object) can give you some light

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You cannot add attributes to an instance of `object` because `object` does not have a [`__dict__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) (which would store the attributes).  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object):

> `class object`
>
> Return a new featureless object. `object` is a base for all classes. It has the methods that are common to all instances of Python classes.
>   This function does not accept any arguments.
>
> **Note:
>   `object` does not have a `__dict__`, so you can’t assign arbitrary attributes to an instance of the `object` class.**

And `object` does have its uses:

1. As stated above, it serves as the base class for all objects in Python.  Everything you see and use ultimately relies on `object`.
2. You can use `object` to create [sentinel values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) which are perfectly unique.  Testing them with `is` and `is not` will only return `True` when an exact `object` instance is given.
3. In Python 2.x, you can (should) inherit from `object` to create a [new-style class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python).  New-style classes have enhanced functionality and better support.  Note that all classes are automatically new-style in Python 3.x.

Comment: It also comes handy in generating unique objects that we can use as sentinel value(we cannot use `None` everywhere).

Comment: I use it occasionally to create a unique object (with a unique `id`) that can be used as a special marker or [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) when processing data that might contain `None` or zero-length items which are valid non-sentinel values.

Comment: Trey Hunner has a good, comprehensive, article on using `object()` as a sentinel [here](https://treyhunner.com/2019/03/unique-and-sentinel-values-in-python/).