# what condition will cause while loop stop in itertools.groupby() source code

Tags: python, python-itertools

I saw this code in here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby

```
class groupby:
    # [k for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')] --> A B C D A B
    # [list(g) for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCD')] --> AAAA BBB CC D
    def __init__(self, iterable, key=None):
        if key is None:
            key = lambda x: x
        self.keyfunc = key
        self.it = iter(iterable)
        self.tgtkey = self.currkey = self.currvalue = object()
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        self.id = object()
        while self.currkey == self.tgtkey:
            self.currvalue = next(self.it)    # Exit on StopIteration
            self.currkey = self.keyfunc(self.currvalue)
        self.tgtkey = self.currkey
        return (self.currkey, self._grouper(self.tgtkey, self.id))
    def _grouper(self, tgtkey, id):
        while self.id is id and self.currkey == tgtkey:
            yield self.currvalue
            try:
                self.currvalue = next(self.it)
            except StopIteration:
                return
            self.currkey = self.keyfunc(self.currvalue)
```

In the condition of `while self.id is id and self.currkey == tgtkey:`, I want know what kind of condition will cause `self.id is id` to become `False`?

Comment: can you explain why you need that. I am not coming of as rude but even though you have tried to explain the problem i am still  not getting it

Comment: Another call to next is the only way you can do it. If you call next before the previous iterator is exhausted, you will run into this condition.

Comment: @Roushan. It's an example worth learning from, which is why the official docs provide it. The logic is definitely not immediately apparent.

Comment: This may help as additional reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306371/what-is-object-good-for

Comment: @MadPhysicist  I know call to next until iterator runs of item so that it raises StopIteration . But how do you know he needs it. Also if his needs are somewhat else it may be a bad thing to call next since it changes state of the generator. I hope you would also understand not only i have read the docs but also have read the official python code written in C. The User needs need to be know before any solution could be provided

Comment: @Roushan. I don't think you're understanding what OP is asking.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `while self.id is id and self.currkey == tgtkey:` reads roughly as "while the user hasn't called `next` again, and we are in the same group:". `self.id` is an attribute set by `__next__`. The local reference `id` is the reference in `_grouper` to what `self.id` was when it got called. Since every call to `next` generates a new `object`, the check is equivalent to asking if `__next__` has been called since `grouper` started.

Remember that the `groupby` object does not have to operate on stored sequences. The input can be a lazy generator. Notice that the functions always read ahead to ensure that the next item is in the current group, and only yield it if it is. The first part of `__next__` consumes the remainer of the iterator until the next group starts, to fulfill exactly that part of the contract in case you ask for the next group before the current one is consumed.