# Basic Python Inheritance Issue

Tags: python, inheritance

I have the following two classes set up:

```
class Player:

    POINTS_PER_PASSING_YARD = 0.04
    POINTS_PER_PASSING_TOUCHDOWN = 4
    POINTS_PER_INTERCEPTION = -1
    POINTS_PER_RUSHING_YARD = 0.1
    POINTS_PER_RUSHING_TOUCHDOWN = 6
    POINTS_PER_RUSHING_FUMBLE = -2
    POINTS_PER_RECEPTION_YARD = 0.1
    POINTS_PER_RECEPTION_TOUCHDOWN = 6

def __init__(self, name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles):
    self.name = name
    self.team = team
    self.rushingYards = rushingYards
    self.rushingTouchdowns = rushingTouchdowns
    self.rushingFumbles= rushingFumbles

def calculatePoints(self):
    return self.rushingYards * POINTS_PER_RUSHING_YARD + self.rushingTouchdowns * POINTS_PER_RUSHING_TOUCHDOWN + self.rushingFumbles * POINTS_PER_RUSHING_FUMBLE

def toString(self):
    return "name: " + self.name + " team: " + self.team + " passing yards: " + self.passingYards + " rushing yards: " + self.rushingYards + " touchdowns: " + self.touchdowns + " interceptions: " +     self.interceptions
```

Then I have a QB class that inherits from Player:

from Player import *

```
class QB(Player):
    def __init__(self, name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles, passingYards, passingTouchdowns, interceptions, position="QB"):
        super().__init__(self, name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles)
        self.passingYards = passingYards
        self.passingTouchdowns = passingTouchdowns
        self.interceptions = interceptions

    def toString(self):
        return "position: " + self.position + super().toString()
```

Then in my main class, I simply do:

```
myQB = QB("Brees", "Saints", 0, 0, 0, 4952, 33, 17)
print(myQB)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 32, in main
    myQB = QB("Brees", "Saints", 0, 0, 0, 4952, 33, 17)
  File "/Users/benjaminclayman/Desktop/Aurora_Fantasy_Football/QB.py", line 5, in __init__
    Player.__init__(self, name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

But I'm not sure why, since all of the init methods I've written *do* take parameters...

Any idea what's going wrong?

Thanks,
bclayman

Comment: Which version of python are you using? (2 or 3?)

Comment: (because I can't reproduce in python 3.4.)

Comment: @NightShadeQueen I was able to reproduce this - `TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters` , with the `__init__()` method missing from  `Player` class.

Comment: Something seems a bit strange. You are using `super` in the manner permitted for Python 3, which means that even though your `Player` class does not explicitly subclass `object`, it is still a new-style class and the use of `super` like this should just work. But the fact that `Player` is not explicitly a new-style class makes me wonder if you're somehow using this in Python 2? Can you clarify?

Comment: Oh, point, I fixed the indentation when testing. I get `TypeError: __init__() takes 6 positional arguments but 7 were given` when the indents are fixed.

Comment: In Python 2 you should get a different error, since `super` in Python 2 requires at least one argument. So it seems more likely that it is Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your indentation in the first script (with the `Player` class) is correct, then that is the issue.

According to your indentation , the `__init__()` method and other methods are outside the class `Player` , so `Player` uses `object` class' `__init__()` , which does not take any parameters (other than `self` , though we do not need to pass it explicitly ).

You may want to fix the indentation so that all the instance methods (that you intended to be inside `Player` class) come inside the `Player` class.

Example -

```
class Player:

    POINTS_PER_PASSING_YARD = 0.04
    POINTS_PER_PASSING_TOUCHDOWN = 4
    POINTS_PER_INTERCEPTION = -1
    POINTS_PER_RUSHING_YARD = 0.1
    POINTS_PER_RUSHING_TOUCHDOWN = 6
    POINTS_PER_RUSHING_FUMBLE = -2
    POINTS_PER_RECEPTION_YARD = 0.1
    POINTS_PER_RECEPTION_TOUCHDOWN = 6

    def __init__(self, name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles):
        self.name = name
        self.team = team
        self.rushingYards = rushingYards
        self.rushingTouchdowns = rushingTouchdowns
        self.rushingFumbles= rushingFumbles
```

You will need to do this for all methods you intended to be inside `Player` class.

---

One more issue, you should not pass `self` in to te `__init__()` method called using `super()` .

Example -

```
class QB(Player):
    def __init__(self, name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles, passingYards, passingTouchdowns, interceptions, position="QB"):
        super().__init__(name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles)
```

Answer (score 0):

Few issues, first you need to fix your indentation.

second, you should change

```
 this class Player:
```

TO

```
 class Player(object):
```

another issue is when you call a static member this is the way to handle them:

```
Player.POINTS_PER_RUSHING_YARD  # name of the class and then the static member.
```

This is how your super should look like:

```
super(QB, self).__init__(name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles)
```

This is the code:

```
    class Player(object):
    POINTS_PER_PASSING_YARD = 0.04
    POINTS_PER_PASSING_TOUCHDOWN = 4
    POINTS_PER_INTERCEPTION = -1
    POINTS_PER_RUSHING_YARD = 0.1
    POINTS_PER_RUSHING_TOUCHDOWN = 6
    POINTS_PER_RUSHING_FUMBLE = -2
    POINTS_PER_RECEPTION_YARD = 0.1
    POINTS_PER_RECEPTION_TOUCHDOWN = 6
    def __init__(self, name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles):
        self.name = name
        self.team = team
        self.rushingYards = rushingYards
        self.rushingTouchdowns = rushingTouchdowns
        self.rushingFumbles= rushingFumbles
    def calculatePoints(self):
        return self.rushingYards * Player.POINTS_PER_RUSHING_YARD + self.rushingTouchdowns * Player.POINTS_PER_RUSHING_TOUCHDOWN + self.rushingFumbles * Player.POINTS_PER_RUSHING_FUMBLE
    def toString(self):
        return "name: " + self.name + " team: " + self.team + " passing yards: " + self.passingYards + " rushing yards: " + self.rushingYards + " touchdowns: " + self.touchdowns + " interceptions: " +     self.interceptions


class QB(Player):
    def __init__(self, name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles, passingYards, passingTouchdowns, interceptions, position="QB"):
        super(QB, self).__init__(name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles)
        self.passingYards = passingYards
        self.passingTouchdowns = passingTouchdowns
        self.interceptions = interceptions

    def toString(self):
       return "position: " + self.position + super(Player).toString()


myQB = QB("Brees", "Saints", 0, 0, 0, 4952, 33, 17)
print(myQB)
```

Comment: Why is this necessary - `class Player(object):` ? By default the parent class is `object` , unless specified otherwise?

Comment: And I am guessing the above code is Python 3.x , in which case `super()` is fine.

Comment: @AnandSKumar , New style objects have a different object model to classic objects, and some things won't work properly with old style objects, for instance, super(), property and descriptors. - taken from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object

Comment: @ omri_saadon Old style objects are no longer there in Python 3, (I am guessing user is using Python 3) , as otherwise OP would be getting a different error when trying to use `super()` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar Didn't noticed for python 3.x, I'm using 2.x.. my mistake

Answer (score 0):

In Python the indentation plays the major role. 
List of Issues:
1) The `__init__()` should be within the class Player. Otherwise your initialization will not work.

2) The Other functions `def calculatePoints(self`), should also be within the `class Player`. Currently in your code it is defined outside the class.

3) The `def toString(self)` should also be within the `class Player`.

```
3.1) Also the concatenation of string and int is not permitted. 
3.2) The variable `self.touchdowns` is not initialized in the def toString of class Player.
3.3) The alternate way to print the class with significant information 
     about class can be written in this manner.

class Player:
    POINTS_PER_PASSING_YARD = 0.04
    POINTS_PER_PASSING_TOUCHDOWN = 4
    POINTS_PER_INTERCEPTION = -1
    POINTS_PER_RUSHING_YARD = 0.1
    POINTS_PER_RUSHING_TOUCHDOWN = 6
    POINTS_PER_RUSHING_FUMBLE = -2
    POINTS_PER_RECEPTION_YARD = 0.1
    POINTS_PER_RECEPTION_TOUCHDOWN = 6

    def __init__(self, name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles):
        self.name = name
        self.team = team
        self.rushingYards = rushingYards
        self.rushingTouchdowns = rushingTouchdowns
        self.rushingFumbles= rushingFumbles

    def calculatePoints(self):
        return self.rushingYards * POINTS_PER_RUSHING_YARD + self.rushingTouchdowns * POINTS_PER_RUSHING_TOUCHDOWN + self.rushingFumbles * POINTS_PER_RUSHING_FUMBLE

    def __str__(self):
        return "name: %s team: %s passing yards: %r rushing yards: %r rushingTouchdowns: %r interceptions: %r"  % (self.name, self.team, self.passingYards, self.rushingYards, self.rushingTouchdowns ,self.interceptions)
```

4) `self.position = position` need to be initialized in the `class QB`, like this:

```
class QB(Player):
    def __init__(self, name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles, passingYards, passingTouchdowns, interceptions, position="QB"):
        super().__init__(name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles)
        self.passingYards = passingYards
        self.passingTouchdowns = passingTouchdowns
        self.interceptions = interceptions
        self.position = position

    def __str__(self):
        return "position: " + self.position + super().__str__()
```