# passing arguments from python gtk function

Tags: python-3.x, parameter-passing, gtk3

I am trying to pass the "filename" from the function `on_file_open_clicked` defined as:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango

UI_INFO = """
<ui>
  <menubar name='MenuBar'>
      <menu action='FileMenu'>
      <menuitem action='FileOpen' />
      <menuitem action='FileQuit' />
    </menu>
  </menubar>
</ui>
"""

class MenuManager(Gtk.UIManager):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        action_group = Gtk.ActionGroup("my_actions")
        self.add_file_menu_actions(action_group)
        self.add_ui_from_string(UI_INFO)
        self.insert_action_group(action_group)

    def add_file_menu_actions(self, action_group):
        action_group.add_actions([
            ("FileMenu", None, "New"),
            ("FileOpen", Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, None, None, None,
             self.file_open_clicked),
            ("FileQuit", Gtk.STOCK_QUIT, None, None, None,
             self.on_menu_file_quit),
        ])


    def file_open_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open an existing fine", None,
                                       Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
                                       (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,
                                        Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                                        Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
        response = dialog.run()
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            filename = dialog.get_filename()
            print(filename)
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print("Cancel clicked")
        dialog.destroy()


    def on_menu_file_quit(self, widget):
        Gtk.main_quit()
```

The calling function is defined as:

```
import gi
import menu
from pybib import parsing_read
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="mkBiB")

        MenuElem = menu.MenuManager()
        menubar = MenuElem.get_widget("/MenuBar")
        box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        box.pack_start(menubar, False, False, 0)
        self.add(box)
        print(filename)
win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

obviously, since `filename` is not defined in calling function, it is giving error. But I don't know how to retrieve filename from `on_file_open_clicked`.

Kindly help.

**Edit: Why I need the filename**
Since the program pasted above is a minimal one, I have not shown what I will do with the `filename`. Actually, the filename is a argument of another routine(that is pure python, nothing to do with gtk3). So, the calling and interface is like:
**in main**

```
filename = "../Trial.bib"   #I am working with hardcoded file for now
                            # This is where I need filename from menu.
parsing_read(filename, booklist)
```

The parsing_read is:

```
def parsing_read(filename, booklist):
```

Comment: *since filename is not defined in main function* - where is the main function?

Comment: Just below the line 'The main function is defined as'

Comment: Edited and "main function" is changed to "calling function"

Comment: @BaRud: This looks like an XY problem. What do you need to do with the filename? It seems from all your questions, that you did not grasp yet how event-driven programming works. The Gtk.main() function will not return until the window is closed, which is supposed to occur only when closing the program. So you my guess is that you do not need to "return" the filename. Depending on if you accept to freeze your interface, you can either do the operations on the file directly, or you need to push the task in a thread.

Comment: @Cilyan: Thanks for your comment. I have put my intention by editing the question