# Checking if a class is iterable

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, iterable

I have a class `fib` given below. It implements `__iter__` and `__next__`. It is an iterable as well as its own iterator.

```
class fib(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.prev = 0
        self.curr = 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        value = self.curr
        self.curr += self.prev
        self.prev = value
        return value


from collections import Iterable

print(isinstance(fib, Iterable))
```

The print statement returns `False`, I would expect it to return `True`

Comment: `fib` is the *class*, not an instance. So you would use the subclass check `issubclass(fib, Iterable)`. Or you create an instance first: `isinstance(fib(), Iterable)` – That’s what you get for starting your class name with a lower case character ;)

Comment: `fib` is not iterable. `fib` is a class whose instances are iterable. Trying to iterate over `fib` itself would be like trying to eat the concept of burgers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checking if an object is iterable is correctly, as you've done, performed with:

```
isinstance(obj, collections.Iterable)
```

The problem here is you're supplying a `class` to `isinstance` and not an instance. It is `False` because `isinstance` will go ahead and check if `type(fib)` has an `__iter__` method defined:

```
type(fib).__iter__  # AttributeError
```

This of course, isn't the case. `type(fib)` is `type` which doesn't define an `__iter__` method.

If you supply an instance to it, it correctly prints `True`:

```
isinstance(fib(), Iterable)  # True
```

because looking in `type(fib())` it will find `fib.__iter__`.

Alternatively, feeding `fib` to `issubclass` performs a similar check that, instead, takes a class as a first argument:

```
issubclass(fib, Iterable)    # True
```

Two extra minor things to point out:

- Using `object` as an explicit base class is unnecessary in Python `3` (though, if you're developing code that runs on both Py2 and Py3, it is a good thing. (See [Python class inherits object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object/45062077#45062077) for more on this.)
- According to PEP 8, class names should follow the CapWords convention, so `fib` should ideally be named `Fib`.