# python missing attribute in inherited class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting a strange issue where one class has a `score_card` attribute, and another class inherits it by using `super().__init__`, but the object instance says that it does *not* have a `score_card` attribute.

The following example *works*:

```
 class ScoreCard:
    def report(self, severity, message):
        print('report.')

class Typeable:
    @property
    def type(self):
        return self._type
    @type.setter
    def type(self, new_type):
        self._type = new_type

class Node(Typeable):
    def __init__(self, dic):
        self.score_card = ScoreCard()

class Definition(Node):
    def __init__(self, dic):
        self.type = "definition"
        super().__init__(dic)
        self.score_card.report("critical", "NEEDS_NAME")

class Axiom(Definition):
    def __init__(self, dic):
        self.type = "axiom"
        super().__init__(dic)




#######################


a = Axiom({})
```

But the same code within the larger program does *not* work.  There must be something completely unexpected coming into play:

```
 ############################# IMPORTS ############################
import sys
from warnings import warn
import subprocess
import copy
import re
import json
from string import punctuation

from lib import helper
from lib.vote import Votable
from lib.config import ERR

######################## INTERNAL HELPERS ########################


class ScoreCard: # this will eventually be moved to its own file


    def __init__(self):
        # a stack of reports
        self.stack = []

    FAILING_SCORE = 40

    SEVERITY_WORD_TO_NUMBER = {
        "low": 5,
        "medium": 10,
        "high": 20,
        "critical": FAILING_SCORE,
    }

    def severity_string_to_number(self, string):
        assert isinstance(string, str)
        words = string.split("-")
        numbers = [self.SEVERITY_WORD_TO_NUMBER[word] for word in words]
        number = sum(numbers) / len(numbers) # the average severity
        return number

    def report(self, severity_string, message):
        severity_number = self.severity_string_to_number(severity_string)
        self.stack.append((severity_number, message))

    def total_score(self):
        scores = [report[0] for report in self.stack]
        return sum(scores)
        # why is my score 0?  Well, since there is no description, it didn't even attempt to set a descruption in the first place.  Maybe the description should be an EMPTY STRING instead of not setting one.  Or maybe some smarter way?

    def is_passing(self):
        return self.total_score() < self.FAILING_SCORE

    def as_dict(self):
        dic = self.as_dict()
        # make sure d.stack is nice
        # make sure is_passing is nice
        # delete unneeded keys
        return dic


def remove_outer_dunderscores(s):
    # takes in a string like "__hi__", and returns "hi"
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[:2] == "__" and s[-2:] == "__":
        s = s[2:-2]
    return s

def to_bash():
    # include commands here to be executed in bash
    bash_out = subprocess.check_output('ls; cd; ls', shell=True)
    print(bash_out)
    subprocess.call('mkdir test_folder', shell=True)

def move_attribute(dic, aliases, strict=True):
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if key in aliases:
            del dic[key]
            return value
    if strict:
        raise KeyError('Could not find any of the following keys: {} in the soon-to-be Node {}.'.format(aliases, dic))
    else:
        return None

def is_capitalized(value):
    if re.search(r'[\$A-Z]', value): # starts with LaTeX or capital letter
        return True
    return False

def check_type_and_clean(value, value_type, list_of=False):
    if list_of:
        if type(value) is list:
            clean_value = []
            for el in value:
                if type(el) is value_type:
                    if value_type is not str or el.strip() != '': # if value_type is str, we still exclude ''
                        clean_value.append(el)
                elif (el is None or el.strip() == '') and value_type != 'NoneType' and value_type is not None:
                    pass # ignore the blank entry
                else:
                    raise Exception('Element {} is not of type {}'.format(el, value_type))
            value = clean_value
        elif value is None:
            value = [value_type()] # i'm afraid
        else:
            assert type(value) is value_type
            value = [value]
    else:
        assert type(value) is value_type
    return value

def find_key(dic, keys):
    for key in dic:
        if key in keys:
            return key
    raise KeyError('Could not find any of the following keys in the Node input: ' + str(keys))

def dunderscore_count(string):
    dunderscore_list = re.findall(r'__', string)
    return len(dunderscore_list)

def get_contents_of_dunderscores(string):
    list_contents = re.findall(r'(?<=__)[^_]*(?=__)', string) # we only want the first one, but contents is a list
    assert list_contents != [] and list_contents[0] != ""
    return list_contents[0]

def reduce_string(string):
    return re.sub(r'[_\W]', '', string).lower()

######################## EXTERNAL HELPERS ########################
def create_appropriate_node(dic):
    # for writers that use shortcut method, we must seek out the type:
    if not 'type' in dic:
        dic['type'] = find_key(dic, {'axiom', 'definition', 'defn', 'def', 'theorem', 'thm', 'exercise'})
        dic['description'] = move_attribute(dic, {'axiom', 'definition', 'defn', 'def', 'theorem', 'thm', 'exercise'})

    if dic['type'] in {'definition', 'defn', 'def'}:
        return Definition(dic)
    elif dic['type'] == 'axiom':
        return Axiom(dic)
    elif dic['type'] in {'theorem', 'thm'}:
        return Theorem(dic)
    elif dic['type'] == 'exercise':
        return Exercise(dic)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Cannot detect type of node.  "type" key has value: ' + dic['type'])

def find_node_from_id(list_of_nodes, ID):
    for node in list_of_nodes:
        if node.id == ID:
            return node
    warn('Could node find node with ID "' + ID + '" within list_of_nodes.')


############################## MAIN ##############################


class Typeable: # created specifically for Node


    @property
    def type(self):
        return self._type
    @type.setter
    def type(self, new_type):
        clean_type = check_type_and_clean(new_type, str)
        if clean_type in {'definition', 'defn', 'def'}:
            self._type = 'definition'
        elif clean_type in {'axiom'}:
            self._type = 'axiom'
        elif clean_type in {'theorem', 'thm'}:
            self._type = 'theorem'
        elif clean_type in {'exercise'}:
            self._type = 'exercise'
        else:
            raise TypeError(ERR["BAD_TYPE"](clean_type))


class Node(Typeable, Votable):


    MIN_IMPORTANCE = 1
    MAX_IMPORTANCE = 10
    # ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES = ['name', 'id', 'type', 'importance', '_importance', 'description', 'intuitions', 'dependencies', 'examples', 'counterexamples', 'notes']

    # Pass in a single json dictionary (dic) in order to convert to a node
    def __init__(self, dic):
        # clean the input dictionary
        empty_keys = []
        for key, value in dic.items():
            if value == "":
                empty_keys.append(key)
        for key in empty_keys:
            del dic[key]

        # create a score card to score this node as it is initialized
        self.score_card = ScoreCard()
        print('score ME')

        # populate node
        self.description = move_attribute(dic, {'description', 'content'}, strict=False)
        self.dependencies = move_attribute(dic, {'dependencies'}, strict=False)
        self.importance = move_attribute(dic, {'importance', 'weight'}, strict=False)
        self.intuitions = move_attribute(dic, {'intuitions', 'intuition'}, strict=False)
        self.examples = move_attribute(dic, {'examples', 'example'}, strict=False)
        self.counterexamples = move_attribute(dic, {'counterexample', 'counterexamples', 'counter example', 'counter examples'}, strict=False)
        self.notes = move_attribute(dic, {'note', 'notes'}, strict=False)
        self.name = move_attribute(dic, {'name'}, strict=False)

        # we might want to freeze the score card here, or something

    def validate_content_clean(self, value):
        if type(value) is list:
            for el in value:
                self.validate_content_clean(el)
        if type(value) is str:
            # this needs to know WHICH method is the called.  Description callers should get higher penalties, etc.
            if not len(value) >= 15: # arbitary length to make sure person actually put some content in
                self.score_card.report("low-medium", ERR["LENGTH_TOO_SHORT"])
            if not is_capitalized(value):
                # we need to move this ONLY to the things that need to be capitalized (for example, not names)
                self.score_card.report("low", ERR["NOT_CAPITALIZED"])
            return True
        return True

    def as_dict(self):
        dic = self.__dict__
        if 'score_card' in dic:
            del dic['score_card']
        return dic

    def as_json(self): # returns json version of self
        return json.dumps(self.as_dict())

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.as_dict())

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Node(' + self.__str__() + ')'

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.as_dict().values())

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def clone(self):
        return copy.deepcopy(self)

    @property
    def name(self):
        if '_name' in self.as_dict():
            return self._name
        else:
            return None
    @name.setter
    def name(self, new_name):
        if new_name is None:
            new_name = ""
        if new_name is not None:
            assert dunderscore_count(new_name) == 0
            self._name = check_type_and_clean(new_name, str)
            self.id = self.name
        else:
            self._name = check_type_and_clean(new_name, type(None))

    @property
    def id(self):
        print(self)
        return self._id
    @id.setter
    def id(self, new_id_before_reduction):
        self._id = reduce_string(new_id_before_reduction)

    @property
    def importance(self):
        return self._importance
    @importance.setter
    def importance(self, new_importance):
        if new_importance is None:
            new_importance = -1
        if new_importance is not None:
            if isinstance(new_importance, str):
                new_importance = int(new_importance)
            new_importance = check_type_and_clean(new_importance, int) # but in the future we will accept decimals (floats) too!
            if new_importance < self.MIN_IMPORTANCE:
                self.score_card.report("low", ERR["IMPORTANCE_TOO_LOW"](self, new_importance))
            new_importance = max(self.MIN_IMPORTANCE, new_importance)
            if new_importance > self.MAX_IMPORTANCE:
                self.score_card.report("low", ERR["IMPORTANCE_TOO_HIGH"](self, new_importance))
            new_importance = min(self.MAX_IMPORTANCE, new_importance)
        self._importance = new_importance

    @property
    def description(self):
        return self._description
    @description.setter
    def description(self, new_description):
        if new_description is None:
            new_description = ""
        clean_description = check_type_and_clean(new_description, str)
        self.validate_content_clean(clean_description)
        self._description = clean_description

    @property
    def intuitions(self):
        return self._intuitions
    @intuitions.setter
    def intuitions(self, new_intuitions):
        clean_intuitions = check_type_and_clean(new_intuitions, str, list_of=True)
        self.validate_content_clean(clean_intuitions)
        for x in clean_intuitions:
            if dunderscore_count(x) > 0:
                self.score_card.report("low", ERR["DUNDERSCORES"](x))
        self._intuitions = clean_intuitions

    @property
    def dependencies(self):
        return self._dependencies
    @dependencies.setter
    def dependencies(self, new_dependencies):
        cleaned_dependencies = check_type_and_clean(new_dependencies, str, list_of=True)
        cleaned_dependencies = remove_outer_dunderscores(cleaned_dependencies)
        for d in cleaned_dependencies:
            if dunderscore_count(d) > 0:
                self.score_card.report("critical", ERR["DUNDERSCORES"](d))
        self._dependencies = cleaned_dependencies

    @property
    def dependency_ids(self):
        return [reduce_string(x) for x in self.dependencies]

    @property
    def examples(self):
        return self._examples
    @examples.setter
    def examples(self, new_examples):
        cleaned_examples = check_type_and_clean(new_examples, str, list_of=True)
        self.validate_content_clean(cleaned_examples)
        for x in cleaned_examples:
            if dunderscore_count(x) > 0:
                self.score_card.report("low", ERR["DUNDERSCORES"](x))
        self._examples = cleaned_examples

    @property
    def counterexamples(self):
        return self._counterexamples
    @counterexamples.setter
    def counterexamples(self, new_counterexamples):
        cleaned_counterexamples = check_type_and_clean(new_counterexamples, str, list_of=True)
        self.validate_content_clean(cleaned_counterexamples)
        for x in cleaned_counterexamples:
            if dunderscore_count(x) > 0:
                self.score_card.report("low", ERR["DUNDERSCORES"](x))
        self._counterexamples = cleaned_counterexamples

    @property
    def notes(self):
        return self._notes
    @notes.setter
    def notes(self, new_notes):
        cleaned_notes = check_type_and_clean(new_notes, str, list_of=True)
        self.validate_content_clean(cleaned_notes)
        # notes may mention a synonym, so we will allow dunderscores (open to discussion)
        self._notes = cleaned_notes


class Definition(Node):


    # ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES = ['name', 'id', 'type', 'importance', 'description', 'intuitions', 'dependencies', 'examples', 'counterexamples', 'notes', 'plurals']

    def __init__(self, dic):
        self.type = "definition"
        super().__init__(dic)
        self.plurals = move_attribute(dic, {'plurals', 'plural', 'pl'}, strict=False)
        self.negation = move_attribute(dic, {'negation'}, strict=False)
        if self.importance is None:
            self.importance = 4
        if self.description in [None, '']:
            if self.name in [None, '']:
                self.score_card.report("critical", NEEDS_NAME)
        else:
            if self.name in [None, ''] and dunderscore_count(self.description) < 2:
                self.score_card.report("critical", NEEDS_NAME)
            if self.name not in [None, ''] and dunderscore_count(self.description) < 2:
                pass
            if self.name in [None, ''] and dunderscore_count(self.description) >= 2:
                print('GETTING')
                self.name = get_contents_of_dunderscores(self.description)

    @property
    def plurals(self):
        return self._plurals
    @plurals.setter
    def plurals(self, new_plurals):
        if new_plurals is None:
            self._plurals = []
        else:
            cleaned_plurals = check_type_and_clean(new_plurals, str, list_of=True)
            self._plurals = cleaned_plurals

    @property
    def negation(self):
        return self._negation
    @negation.setter
    def negation(self, new_negation):
        if new_negation is None:
            self._negation = None
        else:
            clean_negation = check_type_and_clean(new_negation, str)
            clean_negation = remove_outer_dunderscores(clean_negation)
            if dunderscore_count(clean_negation) > 0:
                self.score_card.report("medium", ERR["DUNDERSCORES"](clean_negation))
            self._negation = clean_negation

    @Node.description.setter
    def description(self, new_description):
        if new_description is None:
            new_description = ""
        if dunderscore_count(new_description) < 2:
            self.score_card.report("low", ERR["NO_DUNDERSCORES"](new_description))
        Node.description.fset(self, new_description)


class Axiom(Definition):


    def __init__(self, dic):
        self.type = "axiom"
        super().__init__(dic)

    @property
    def dependencies(self):
        return []
    @dependencies.setter
    def dependencies(self, new_deps):
        if new_deps is None or (isinstance(new_deps, list) and not new_deps):
            self._dependencies = []
        else:
            if "justification" in dic:
                # as Mo pointed out, axioms CAN have dependencies.  Perhaps there are some definitions you create first, and then an AXIOM uses those definitions (but still introduces something you must accept on faith alone).
                pass
            else:
                # now we will even allow the user to make axioms with deps, so the fset is below this block.
                self.score_card.report("medium", ERR["AXIOM_WITH_DEPENDENCY"])
        Node.dependencies.fset(self, new_deps)


class PreTheorem(Node):


    # ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES = ['name', 'id', 'type', 'importance', 'description', 'intuitions', 'dependencies', 'examples', 'counterexamples', 'notes', 'proofs']

    def __init__(self, dic):
        super().__init__(dic)
        print('BELOW COMMENTED OUT TO DISABLE PROOFS')
        # self.proofs = move_attribute(dic, {'proofs', 'proof'}, strict=False)



        # theorems and exercises CANNOT have plurals: (but since we only created plural for Definitions, we shouldn't need this as long as there is a way to block undefined properties (see other Stack Overflow question))
        if 'plurals' in self.as_dict():
            raise KeyError('Theorems cannot have plurals.')

    @property
    def proofs(self):
        return self._proofs
    @proofs.setter
    def proofs(self, new_proofs):
        good_type_proofs = check_type_and_clean(new_proofs, dict, list_of=True)
        self.validate_content_clean(good_type_proofs)
        for proof in good_type_proofs:
            proof['description'] = move_attribute(proof, {'description', 'content'}, strict=True)
            if dunderscore_count(proof['description']) > 0:
                self.score_card.report("low", ERR["DUNDERSCORES"](proof['description']))
            if 'type' not in proof:
                self.score_card.report("low", ERR["NO_PROOF_TYPE"])
                # then give some default type to the proof
                proof['type'] = None
            proof['type'] = check_type_and_clean(proof['type'], str, list_of=True)
        self._proofs = good_type_proofs

    @Node.description.setter
    def description(self, new_description):
        if dunderscore_count(new_description) != 0:
            self.score_card.report("medium-high", DUNDERSCORE(new_description))
        Node.description.fset(self, new_description)


class Theorem(PreTheorem):


    MIN_IMPORTANCE = 3
    # ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES = ['name', 'id', 'type', 'importance', 'description', 'intuitions', 'dependencies', 'examples', 'counterexamples', 'notes', 'proofs']


    def __init__(self, dic):
        self.type = "theorem"
        super().__init__(dic)
        if self.importance is None:
            self.importance = 6
        if self.name is None:
            self.score_card.report("critical", ERR["NO_NAME"]) # maybe lower this if we can auto-assign a name

    @PreTheorem.name.setter
    def name(self, new_name):
        if new_name is not None:
            self.score_card.report("critical", ERR["NO_NAME"]) # maybe lower this if we can auto-assign a name
        PreTheorem.name.fset(self, new_name)


class Exercise(PreTheorem):


    MAX_IMPORTANCE = 3
    # ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES = ['name', 'id', 'type', 'importance', 'description', 'intuitions', 'dependencies', 'examples', 'counterexamples', 'notes', 'proofs']

    def __init__(self, dic):
        self.type = "exercise"
        super().__init__(dic)
        if self.importance is None:
            self.importance = 1

    @PreTheorem.description.setter
    def description(self, new_description):
        PreTheorem.description.fset(self, new_description)
        if self.name is None:
            self.id = self.description
```

I am at a loss for why it is missing.  The stack trace says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pre-json_to_mongo.py", line 80, in <module>
    "type": "axiom",
  File "/Users/Matthew/programming/prove-math/server/lib/node.py", line 137, in create_appropriate_node
    return Axiom(dic)
  File "/Users/Matthew/programming/prove-math/server/lib/node.py", line 431, in __init__
    super().__init__(dic)
  File "/Users/Matthew/programming/prove-math/server/lib/node.py", line 382, in __init__
    self.score_card.report("critical", NEEDS_NAME)
AttributeError: 'Axiom' object has no attribute 'score_card'
```

where the original calling line, from another file, is:

```
            dependency_node = create_appropriate_node({
                "name": node.dependencies[i],
                "type": "axiom",
            })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python class inherits object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object)

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm not sure that question is applicable. Can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: `Votable` might be relevant.

Comment: You posted one small working example and one huge non-working example.  Please try to reduce your non-working example to the minimal code that will demonstrate the error.  In doing so, you may even find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def as_dict(self):
    dic = self.__dict__
    if 'score_card' in dic:
        del dic['score_card']
    return dic
```

You deleted the `score_card` attribute! That's why you're getting that `AttributeError`. Don't do that.

Comment: Thank you, kind sir!  Yes, it should have been `dic = copy.deepcopy(self.__dict__)`.