# Run a class without assigning an object to it in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, class

```
class Run(object):

    def run(self):
        print('run, save yourself')

Run().run()
```

it prints out

> 'run, save yourself'

How can we run class and its functions without defining object to it?

We have to assign an object to the class and then run it like

r = Run()

r.run()

Does python automatically assigns the abject to Class and then runs it ?

Comment: What you're asking isn't exactly clear. Could you further clarify what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Comment: what problem are you facing.?

Comment: If you're wondering why we can call this without passing in an "object", it's actually [inheritance and a keyword in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what happens  when you run `Run().run()`:

1- `Run()` creates a `Run` object
2- in turn, this objects calls its method `run()` on itself

This is equivalent to:

```
r = Run()
r.run()
```

Except that in your case, your object Run() is created, then immediately garbage collected because there is nothing pointing to it, after the `run()` method was executed.

Comment: so we can directly run class functions inside any class without assigning it to an object, python will temporarily make an object and then delete it?

Comment: yes, you can create "throwaway" objects, not assigned to any variables, and directly call a method on them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a class to run without having to call `run`, you could try something like this

```
class Run(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        print('run, save yourself')

Run()
>>> run, save yourself
```

Expanding on that, you can also do

```
class Run(object):
    def __call__(self):
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        print('run, save yourself')

r = Run()
r()
>>> run, save yourself
```