# difference between different type of class naming

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

What is difference between both class naming conventions, both resulting in the same output?

```
class class_name:
    def func():
        print('1st class')


class class_name():
    def func():
        print('2nd class')
```

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object) top answer has the answer. It also might clarify why there are brackets in the first place (eg: is the code you're looking at potentially from Python 2 and it may have inherited from `object`?)

Comment: None at all. The difference between `'hello'` and `('hello')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax with parenthesis defines an inheritance relationship. But to inherit no class is the same as using just the class.

[Python DOC on class inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance)

Suppose you had a class called parent:

```
class parent:
    def f1(self):
        print("F1 in action!")
```

And you wanted to use things from parent in another class (usually a relationship like parent: generalisation, child: specialisation). You can derive from that class.

```
class child(parent):
    def f2(self):
        print("F2 in action!")

# Now use child.f2 OR child.f1!
c = child()
c.f1()
c.f2()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is new class syntax vs old class syntax

From [Python's wiki:](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass)

> A "New Class" is the recommended way to create a class in modern Python.
>
> A "Classic Class" or "old-style class" is a class as it existed in Python 2.1 and before. They have been retained for backwards compatibility. This page attempts to list the differences.
>
> The syntax for the two types looks the same; "new-style", "old style", "classic", and variants are just descriptions that various people have used; Python hasn't yet settled on a specific official choice for the terminology.
>
> **The minor syntactic difference is that New Style Classes happen to inherit from object.**

Regarding @Felix question, consider the following:

```
class A: pass
class B(): pass
class C(object): pass

print A.__mro__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    A.__mro__
AttributeError: class A has no attribute '__mro__'

print B.__mro__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    B.__mro__
AttributeError: class B has no attribute '__mro__'

print C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <type 'object'>)
```

You explicity have to inhert from object; there is no default inheritance.

Comment: The `class x():` syntax doesn't default to inheriting from `object`, does it?

Comment: That's a good question, and no it doesn't by default. I'll update my answer with an example