# create/call class instance, error object not defined

Tags: python, class, instance

I haven't created any classes from scratch before. Any previous ones have been super simple. Am I close to creating the class right? I'm confused on how to call an instance of the class. What I want to do is create a `class Book` and assign various values (author name, home directory, output directory, function to get title, function to get .html files from home directory, etc). I want to create a new instance of `class Book` for each `bookList[i]`. `bookList[i]` is each book's homeDir. What is my class and/or instance call missing please? Thanks in advance for all help or pointers.

```
class Book(obj):        
    def __init__(self, inc_dir):
        self.home_dir = inc_dir
        # self.author_name = aName
        # self.target_dir = target_dir

# main #
bookList = getDirs(homeDir) # returns a list. works.
# print("len(bookList): ", len(bookList))     
i = 0    
while i <= len(bookList):
    curBook = Book(bookList[i])
    print("curBook name: " + curBook.home_dir)
    print("Book Path: " + bookList[i])
    i += 1  

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Scripts\Python\batch content editing\html_book_builder.py", line 65, in <module>
        class Book(obj):
    NameError: name 'obj' is not defined
```

Comment: So basically `object` is a predefined default base class. None of the info I was reading ever specifically stated that (to me).  This question is a duplicate. After specifically searching for "python class object keyword" it came up with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object

Answer (score 1):

You're defining the class `Book` to inherit from the class `obj`, and yet there's no such class named `obj`, hence the error. If you mean for the class `Book` to inherit from the base class, you should either make it inherit from the class `object`:

```
class Book(object):
```

or simply omit the parent class specification if you're using Python 3.x:

```
class Book:
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that when you write `class Book(obj)`, the Python interpreter is looking for something named `obj`. You haven't defined `obj` yet, so Python complains that nothing named `obj` has been defined.

You may have seen examples with `object` as follows:

```
class Book(object):
```

These examples are subclassing the **already existing** `object`. There isn't a name error because that thing is already defined. In Python 3, you can get rid of the `object` entirely. You can in Python 2 as well, but the behavior of classes changes a bit in that case (there were quite a few so-called "breaking" changes between 2 and 3).

```
class Book:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is with obj which is passed as an argument for the Class Book.
It is supposed to be **object**(Lower case) in Python 2.x. In Python 3.x, You can just leave it out!