# AttributeError: type object 'DirectView' has no attribute 'as_view'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

here is my views.py  code

```
class DirectView(mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    serializer_class=DirectSerializer
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.create(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

and my urls.py

```
path('direct/',DirectView.as_view(),name='direct'),
```

but whenever i tried to  run the server i get an error as

```
AttributeError: type object 'DirectView' has no attribute 'as_view'
```

i don't understand what the issue is ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `DirectView` class must inherit from a `View` class in Django in order to use [`as_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view).

```
from django.views.generic import View

class DirectView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, View):
```

If you're using the rest framework, maybe the inheritance you need here is [`CreateAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview) or [`GenericAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) (with `CreateModelMixin`) which is the API equivalent of the `View` class mentioned above.

Comment: `django.views.generic.View` and `rest_framework.generics.GenericAPIView` are different. (atleast their `response`)

Comment: @JPG The `GenericAPIView` inherits `APIView` which in turn inherits django's own `View` so you'll have the `as_view()` method there as well. The responses will no doubt differ because `View` is intended as a standard view, whereas the rest views are designed for API responses.

Answer (score 0):

If we are looking into the [source code of **`mixins.CreateModelMixin`**](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L14), we could see it's inherited from [**`object`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object) (***builtin type***) and hence it's independent of any kind of inheritance other than ***builtin type***.
Apart from that, **Mixin** classes are special kind of multiple inheritance. You could read more about Mixins [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful). In short, Mixins provides additional functionality to the class (kind of *helper class*).

---

**So, What's the solution to this problem?**
**Solution - 1 : Use `CreateAPIView`** 
Since you are trying to extend the functionality of `CreateModelMixin`, it's highly recomended to use this DRF builtin view as,

```
from rest_framework import generics


class DirectView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DirectSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

**Reference**
1. [What is a mixin, and why are they useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful)
2. [Python class inherits object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object)