# Class inheritance in Python, super and overridden methods

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding, self

Consider the following code:

```
class A:
    def foo(self, a):
        return a
    def bar(self, a):
        print(foo(a))

class B(A):
   def foo(self, a):
       return a[0]
```

Now calling `B.bar(a)` the result is `print(a[0])`, but what I want is `print(a)`. More directly: I'd like that the calling of `bar()`in a child class uses the definition of `foo`given in `A` even if overridden. How do i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python class inherits object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object)

Comment: I can't find the answer to my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self, a):
        return a
    def bar(self, a):
        print(A.foo(self,a))

class B(A):
   def foo(self, a):
       return a[0]
```

or alternatively:

```
class A:
    def foo(self, a):
        return a
    def bar(self, a):
        print(self.foo(a))

class B(A):
   def foo(self, a):
       return super().foo(a)
```

Comment: Perfect, the first one you written is working as I want! Thanks