# Python - how to pass to a function argument type of a class object (typing)

Tags: python, class, python-3.7, type-hinting

I suppose that came with python 3.7 (not sure), the possibility to pass to a function not only the variable name but also the type of the variable. What I would like to know is if there is any possibility of passing the type of a particular class.

The same way you could pass:

```py
def foo_func(i: int) -> None:
    pass
```

If I have a class let's say:

```py
class foo_class(object):
    pass
```

How could I transform the `foo_func` to receive the `foo_class`instead of the `int`type?

Furthermore, if foo_class was an inheritance of another class could I impose a more general type from the parent? For instance, if I would have,

```py
class A(foo_class):
     pass

class B(foo_class):
     pass
```

How could I pass `A` or `B` based on its parent?

I mean something like:

```py
def foo_func(obj: foo_class_type) -> None:
    pass

foo_func(A())
foo_func(B())
```

Comment: Setting argument type to `type` might solve the problem. For instance: `def foo_func(obj: type)->None:`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Depending on whether you meant to pass a class (type) or an instance of a class, you’re looking for either `typing.Type` or simply the class.

Here’s a simple example to explain both situations:

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar


class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Creating a %s" % self.__class__.__name__)

    def move(self):
        print("This %s is moving…" % self.__class__.__name__)

TVehicle = TypeVar("TVehicle", bound=Vehicle)

class Car(Vehicle):
    def honk(self) -> None:
        print("tuuuuut")

class Bike(Vehicle):
    def ring(self) -> None:
        print("ring")

class Dog:
    def bark(self) -> None:
        print("woof!")


def move(v: Vehicle) -> None:
    v.move()

def instantiate(class_to_instantiate: Type[TVehicle]) -> TVehicle:
    return class_to_instantiate()  # create an instance

move(Bike())
move(Car())

instantiate(Bike).ring()
instantiate(Car).honk()
#instantiate(Dog)
```

`Car` and `Bike` inherit from `Vehicle`, so they both get at least the `move` method and the custom `__init__`, which reveals the name of the class that invoked it.

Now, in the first function, `move`, one simply wants to specify that the argument `v` should be an *instance* of a `Vehicle`. The function calls `Vehicle`’s `move` method, which will reveal the name of the instance’s class from which the call originated.

In the second function, `instantiate`, the goal is to create an instance of a class. This works through [type variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#type-variables), which allow you in this example to specify that there’s a relation between the function’s input argument and output argument: if I were to call `instantiate(Bike)`, I want the return type to be an instance of the `Bike` class, so that I may legally call its `ring` method. If you were to replace the `TVehicle` in this function definition simply by `Vehicle`, your type checking program would complain, because the return type would then be an instance of the `Vehicle` class, for which you do not have a guarantee that the `ring` method exists. 
Finally, the `Type` part that you see in the argument of `instantiate` simply allows you to call the function with a class, so not with an instance of that class. This is useful e.g. in cases where you want to delay instantiation of a class.

Note that this is an example to explain how to do it. In a more professional setting, `Vehicle` would likely be an [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) and some methods here could be given as class methods.

Side notes on your code example:

1. Note that if you don’t intend to write code that also works in Python2, you shouldn’t inherit from `object` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062077/2476444)).
2. Classes are typically written with `CapWord` names, as [specified in PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names), the Python style guide. Following this style makes your code more easily understandable by other developers.

Comment: Rather than declaring a TypeVar and additionally binding it to Vehicle - Type[Vehicle] also worked for me.