# how to use function parameter as class object in Python

Tags: python, function, class, parameters, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to pass a function parameter as a class object but it's not working.
my class is **'Users'** and I want to use ***'request'*** parameter as its object to get some data in the class.

Is it even possible?

here is my code:

```
def users(request, filters):
    result = session.query(Users.request).filter(filters).all()
    return result
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Users' has no attribute 'request'
```

and the parameter request is unused.

Comment: this might be the reference : I don't know it will be the solution or not ?:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55751368/python-how-to-pass-to-a-function-argument-type-of-a-class-object-typing

Comment: Please provide more info about your code and error

Comment: `getattr(Users, request)`? It's not clear what either `Users` or `request` is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your session variable is outside your function, if so you need to call it as a global variable:

```
def users(request, filters):
    global session
    result = session.query(Users.request).filter(filters).all()
    return result
```