# Dynamic exception type checking

Tags: python, exception, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to specify types on some code that catches exceptions, but the exact type of exception is dynamic, i.e. specified at runtime.

Running mypy on the below

```py
from typing import TypeVar

ExceptionType = TypeVar('ExceptionType', bound=BaseException)
def my_func(exception_type: ExceptionType) -> None:
    try:
        pass
    except exception_type:
        pass
```

results in the error:

```
error: Exception type must be derived from BaseException
```

How can I get it to pass type checking?

Comment: You're passing a _type_, not an instance of it: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=a66fa95c2b9504b77f2a0b885466c030. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55751368/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's right - but I think that's what I want? When catching an exception you use the type, not an instance, e.g. `except Exception:` and not `except Exception():`. Also, type checking https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=a66fa95c2b9504b77f2a0b885466c030 for me results in `"type" expects no type arguments, but 1 given`

Comment: Yes, that _is_ what you want, but it's _not what you've told the type system_. And that error suggests you're on an older version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @jonrsharpe's comments, this works:

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar

ExceptionType = TypeVar('ExceptionType', bound=BaseException)
def my_func(exception_type: Type[ExceptionType]) -> None:
    try:
        pass
    except exception_type:
        pass
```

(typing.Type is deprecated since Python 3.9, but you might want to support earlier versions of Python)

Comment: though in this mcve there's no need for the `TypeVar`

Answer (score -2):

You can get it to pass using:

```
from typing import Any

def my_func(exception_type: Any) -> None:
    try:
        pass
    except exception_type:
        pass
```

but the downside of this is that `Any` isn't very specific - it does not enforce that that an Exception type is passed at type check time.