# Empty class constructor (style)

Tags: python, class, oop, pep8

What is a "Pythonic" way to define a class that does not need any constructor parameters?

```
class MyClass:

    # class body
```

or do we need an explicit constructor? i.e.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__:
        pass

    # class body
```

Comment: The second one.

Comment: @Harsha Why...?

Comment: Does the class instantiate without errors if you omit `__init__` entirely? (Yes it does.) Then you don't *need* it.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani An `__init__` method requires at least `self` as a parameter as it is an instance method.

Comment: @deceze Fair enough. My thinking was that maybe "Explicit is better than implicit", as in PEP20 - The Zen of Python (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: Explicitly omitting `__init__` is better than having it implicitly consist solely of `pass`… ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first approach is good enough, unless you want to only use class attributes and not instance attributes
Also every class in Python inherits from object, as explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object)

```
class MyClass:
    pass
```

An example of such classes might be as follows

- A class to store multiple class attributes

```
class MyClass:

    a = 1
    b = 2

print(MyClass.a)
#1
print(MyClass.b)
#2
```

- A custom exception where the constructor is implicitly taken from the base class

```
class MyException(Exception):

    pass

raise MyException
#    raise MyException
#__main__.MyException
```

Comment: Might be worthwhile to include an example? Custom exception types are commonly defined this way, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, can you check my update and see if the two examples make sense @AdamSmith :) and let me know