# object is subclassed during dynamic type creation but not during classic class definition in python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class

We know that this creates a class:

```python
class X:
    a = 1
```

And, in Python 3, [due to new style classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062077/3233388), `X` automatically inherits from `object`, but in Python 2, it doesn't:

```py
>>> X.__bases__ # Python 2
()
>>> X.__bases__ # Python 3
(<class 'object'>,)
```

And [we also know](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) that we can dynamically create such a class using type factory:

```py
X = type("X",(object,), {"a":1})
      name^   ^bases     ^ "class" body
```

However, if we omit the `object` in the *bases* tuple just as we did with `class` syntax, we inherit from `object` in python3 and, unexpectedly, in  python2 as well:

```py
X = type("X", ( ), {"a":1})
               ^ empty bases tuple
```

```py
>>> X.__bases__ # Python 2
(<type 'object'>,)
>>> X.__bases__ # Python 3
(<class 'object'>,)
```

I expected `X.__bases__` to be empty in python 2.
And it's not such a documented feature, I hardly find something about this on internet.

In fact, [python's official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) contradictory states that:

> the bases tuple itemizes the base classes and **becomes the `__bases__` attribute**

But, as shown above, `()` still leads to `(<type 'object'>,)` in Python 2, so it's not really true that it becomes the `__bases__` attribute.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Interesting question. I would start Python with `gdb`, make a coffee and step debug through this. Maybe you'll also find the sword of [Martin the warrior](https://xkcd.com/1722/)? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look into this Python 2 shell.

```
>>> class X1:
...     a = 1
... 
... X2 = type('X2', (), {'a': 1})
>>> type(X1)
0: <type 'classobj'>
>>> type(X2)
1: <type 'type'>
>>> import types
>>> assert types.ClassType is type(X1)
```

[`types.ClassType`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.ClassType) is described as:

> The type of user-defined old-style classes.

Basically `type` in the new-style classes' default metaclass. If you want metaprogramming in the old style, you can use `types.ClassType` in the same way.

```
>>> X3 = types.ClassType('X3', (), {'a': 1})
>>> X3.__bases__
2: ()
```

For the reference, excerpt from Python 2's [New-style and classic classes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes):

> Classes and instances come in two flavors: old-style (or classic) and new-style.
>
> Up to Python 2.1 the concept of `class` was unrelated to the concept of
>   `type`, and old-style classes were the only flavor available.  For an
>   old-style class, the statement `x.__class__` provides the class of *x*, but
>   `type(x)` is always `<type 'instance'>`.  This reflects the fact that all
>   old-style instances, independent of their class, are implemented with a single
>   built-in type, called `instance`.
>
> New-style classes were introduced in Python 2.2 to unify the concepts of
>   `class` and `type`.  A new-style class is simply a user-defined type,
>   no more, no less.  If *x* is an instance of a new-style class, then `type(x)`
>   is typically the same as `x.__class__` (although this is not guaranteed -- a
>   new-style class instance is permitted to override the value returned for
>   `x.__class__`).