# How to check MRO (Method Resolution Order) in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdb, method-resolution-order

In Python 3 I can do the following:

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
...
>>> A.mro()
[<class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
```

But in Python 2.7.16 I get an `AttributeError`:

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
...
>>> A.mro()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class A has no attribute 'mro'
>>> A.__mro__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class A has no attribute '__mro__'
```

I understand that if we convert to "new" style objects (inheriting from `object`) this issue goes away:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
...
>>> A.mro()
[<class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>]
```

But my use case is in `pdb`, and I am dealing with lots of objects which would require lots of refactoring, is there any way to access the MRO with old-style classes?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4015417/1324033 - "In Python 2: always inherit from object explicitly."

Comment: At this point, an old-style class should be considered a bug, not something to work around. Python 2 is all but dead. I'm being mostly, but not entirely, facetious when I say this question is more appropriate for retrocomputing.stackexchange.com than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit resolution order for old-style classes; instead, method resolution depends on the transitive closure of the set of parent classes.

From [*The Python 2.3 Method Resolution Order*](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) (emphasis mine):

> First of all, let me point out that what I am going to say only applies to the new style classes introduced in Python 2.2: **classic classes maintain their old method resolution order, depth first and then left to right**.

The resolution order, if exposed at all as explicit data, would have been an implementation detail, not part of the defined interface by the language.