# How to use a constructor from an external class inside current file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a method `setupUi()` in `Ui_MainWindow` in `design.py` (its a really long method created by PyQt Designer)

```py
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow): # really long method
        self.xyz
        ...
    ...
```

and would like to use it as if it were a method in my main file `app.py` in the `ApplicationWindow` class.

What I want to imitate:

```py
class ApplicationWindow:
    def __init__(self, MainWindow, truss, *args, **kwargs):
        self.setupUi(MainWindow)
        [use self.xyz here]
        ...
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow): # same really long method I want here
        ...
    ...
```

What I tried:

```py
from design import Ui_MainWindow

class ApplicationWindow:
    def __init__(self, MainWindow, truss, *args, **kwargs):
        Ui_MainWindow().setupUi(MainWindow) # this works
        [use self.xyz here] # this does not work
        ...
    ...
```

I want to use the variable `self.xyz` from `Ui_MainWindow` in the `ApplicationWindow` class.

But I get an `AttributeError` for `self.xyz`.

Again, the reason that I want it in a seperate file, is because it's very long.

I'm sure this is a simple fix, as modules work in a similar way. But for some reason it isn't working for me, any ideas?

How I call the function (everything is in OOP/Functional):

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

    truss = FEModel3D
    app = ApplicationWindow(MainWindow, truss)

    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(qapp.exec_())
```

File structure:

```bash
master
├───app.py
├───...
└───design.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating a common parent for `UI_MainWindow` and `ApplicationWindow` (e.g. `ParentWindow`) and extracting `setupUi` into a class method of the `ParentWindow`.

so create in a new file e.g. `parent.py`:

```
class ParentWindow:
  def setupUi(self, window):
    # same definition
```

and now import ParentWindow to both classes and replace `class UI_MainWindow(object):` and `class ApplicationWindow:` with `class UI_MainWindow(ParentWindow)` and `class ApplicationWindow(ParentWindow)`, respectively.

Comment: Do I need the parenthesis in the class definition?

Comment: You would only use parenthesis in the class definition when specifying the parent class. So in `class UI_MainWindow(ParentWindow)` and `class ApplicationWindow(ParentWindow)`, but not in `class ParentWindow`. In regards to why you don't have to write `class ParentWindow(object)` you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062077/6282058).

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a variable to connect the two classes and it worked!

`app.py`

```py
class ApplicationWindow():
    def __init__(self, MainWindow, truss, *args, **kwargs):
        win = Ui_MainWindow()
        win.setupUi(MainWindow)
        self.xyz = win.xyz
```

`design.py` was the same.