# Is it necessary to subclass "object" when defining a new class in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems unnecessary to me.

But I still wondering why some sample codes (python3) still inherit this style.

For example (quoted from *Django 2 by Example*):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EmailAuthBackend(object):
    ....
```

Can someone explain a bit?

Thanks!

Comment: Go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062077/7832176).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary. In Python 2 you had to do this to opt in to new-style classes; in Python 3, *all* classes are automatically "new-style" (old-style doesn't exist), so inheriting from `object` is equivalent to not inheriting from anything.

Likely the code you're seeing is legacy code that was directly adapted from older Python 2 code, or written by someone with Python 2 habits, and they never bothered to remove the explicit `object` base, since it's harmless to leave it in.

Answer (score 1):

No, now this is no longer necessary. I think this code was left for backward compatibility.