# Trying to map instance variables to a dictionary within a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to SO, and learning Python.

I'm trying to create a class so that when an instance of the class is instantiated, the arguments the user inputs are mapped to a class dictionary, and values are taken from the dictionary and stored in the instance variables instead of the arguments the user specified. **Here's my code:**

```
class Card(object):
    '''This class sets up a playing card'''
    
    suits = {'d':'diamonds', 'h':'hearts', 's':'spades', 'c':'clubs'}
    values = {1:'Ace',2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7, 8:8, 9:9, 10:10, 11:'Jack', 12:'Queen', 13:'King'}
    
    def __init__ (self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit
        
    def get_value(self):
        return values[self.value]
    
    def get_suit(self):
        return self.suit
    
    def __str__(self):
        my_card = str(self.value) + ' of ' + str(self.suit)
        return my_card
```

So, if I were to type:

```
my_card = Card (1,'d')
```

And then, call the `get_value` method I made it would return 'Ace'

And if I were to call the `get_suit` method it would return 'diamonds'

And if I printed `my_card`, it would print: Ace of diamonds

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It looks like you just want to use `self.get_value() + ' of ' + self.get_suit()` in `__str__`.

Comment: Just as a side-note, you can omit the `(object)` inheritance when defining the class, unless you'd like to maintain some backwards compatibility with python 2.x, as python 3.x already does that behind the scenes. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062077/7808223) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You are very, very close with what you have already.

Since the `values` and `suits` are attributes of the Card class, you need to access them using the same `self.` notation.

So, your Card class would look like this (comments above lines I changed):

```
class Card(object): 
    '''This class sets up a playing card'''
    suits = {'d':'diamonds', 'h':'hearts', 's':'spades', 'c':'clubs'}
    values = {1:'Ace',2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7, 8:8, 9:9, 10:10, 11:'Jack', 12:'Queen', 13:'King'}

    def __init__ (self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def get_value(self):
        # Access the values dictionary with self.values
        return self.values[self.value]

    def get_suit(self):
        # Same thing for suits!
        return self.suits[self.suit]

    def __str__(self):
        # Changed the accessor for suits to be complete
        my_card = str(self.value) + ' of ' + str(self.suits[self.suit])
        return my_card
```

Alternatively for your `__str__` you could have

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.get_value() + ' of ' + self.get_suit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly you got everything you need... just need to put the pieces together in the right way.

```
class Card():
    def __init__ (self, value, suit):
            self.value = value
            self.suit = suit
            self.suits = {'d':'diamonds', 'h':'hearts', 's':'spades', 'c':'clubs'}
            self.values = {1:'Ace',2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7, 8:8, 9:9, 10:10, 11:'Jack', 12:'Queen', 13:'King'}

    def __str__(self):
            my_card = '{} of {}'.format(self.values[self.value], self.suits[self.suit])
            return my_card
my_card = Card(1, 'd')
print(my_card)
```

Comment: Since `suits` and `values` are attributes of the class in the OP's version, accessing them inside the class without the `self` will produce a `NameError`.

Comment: ah I misenterperated them as global variables. I'll edit.

Comment: While you're at it, in Python the "to String" method is always `__str__`. It's a specific method that gets called when an instance of a class is passed into `print()`. Renaming that as `string()` makes it so you have to call that method every time you print instead of having it implicitly work. :)