# class naming; whats the difference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

what is the difference between this two; `class Person(object):` and `class Person:`

```py
class Person(object):
   
  # Constructor
  def __init__(self, name, id):
    self.name = name
    self.id = id
```

Comment: No difference. All classes are inherited from `object` by default (in python3)

Comment: More info here [Why do Python classes inherit object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/why-do-python-classes-inherit-object)