# How to get '7' attached to each string in a list in Python if it doesn't have 7 already in it?

Tags: python, list

I have been trying to solve a problem where I am given a list as input and I need to show an output with 7 attached to each string value if it doesn't contain a 7 already.

I have created a list and for the case of 7 not included I have attached the '7' using the for loop. So for example: for the input
`["a7", "g", "u"]`, I expect output as `["a7","g7","u7"]` but I am getting the output as follows
`['a7', 'g', 'u', ['a77', 'g7', 'u7']]`

I have tried to put the values in a new list using append but I am not sure how to remove the old values and replace it with new ones in existing list. Following is my code

```
class Solution(object):
    def jazz(self, list=[]):

        for i in range(len(list)):
            if '7' not in list[i]:
                li = [i + '7' for i in list]
                list.append(li)
                return list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Solution()
    lt = ['a7', 'g', 'u']
    print(p.jazz(lt))
```

Comment: Please do not name variables `list`, especially in code which uses `list` objects. This clobbers the built-in `list`, adds confusion, and usually results in very annoying bugs.

Comment: `[i.rstrip('7') + '7' for i in lt]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cleaner and more pythonic solution, no classes required, and much more concise:

```
def jazz(items):
    return [item if '7' in item else item+'7' for item in items]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lt = ['a7', 'g', 'u']
    p = jazz(lt)
    print(p)
```

If you want to modify the original list you can use:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    lt = ['a7', 'g', 'u']
    lt[:] = jazz(lt)
    print(lt)
```

Answer (score 2):

@AviTurner already showed you the simplest way of doing it. I'm just gonna write some point about your solution:

- You don't need to inherit from `object` in Python 3. [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062077/13944524)
- Don't use mutable objects for your parameters' default values unless you know what you're doing. [check here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).
- Don't use built-in names like `list` for your variables.
- You create a list `li` and then you append that, This appends the whole list as a single item. Instead you either want to append individual items or `.extend()` it.
- It's perfectly ok to iterate this way `for i in range(len(something))` but there is a better approach, if you need only the items, you can directly get those items this way : `for item in something`. If you also need the indexes: `for i, item in enumerate(something)`

Comment: great code review :)