# Is there any reason to do to multiple inheritance with object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

While reviewing some code, it has a structure like

```py
class Bar(Foo, object):
```

Which seems like it could easily be written instead as

```py
class Bar(Foo):
```

The functionally appears at least the same the simple chain of inheritance for the purpose of determining method resolution, and both `Foo` and `Bar` are `isinstance()` of `object` in both cases

```
B → F → o

B → F
  ↳ o
```

Is there any practical benefit to a multiple inheritance from `object`?

Comment: This might help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/why-do-python-classes-inherit-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly, no, it shouldn't have any effect, the MRO is still the same:

```
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> class Bar(Foo, object): pass
...
>>> Bar.mro()
[<class '__main__.Bar'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <class 'object'>]
```

So:

```
>>> class Bar(Foo): pass
...
>>> Bar.mro()
[<class '__main__.Bar'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Potentially, I suppose, it could have an effect if any code introspects `__bases__`:

```
>>> class Bar(Foo): pass
...
>>> Bar.__bases__
(<class '__main__.Foo'>,)
>>> class Bar(Foo, object): pass
...
>>> Bar.__bases__
(<class '__main__.Foo'>, <class 'object'>)
```

But I highly suspect this is just a typo

Comment: cheers - the `.__bases__` discrepancy is certainly interesting and closer to reality than things like using `inspect` to discover they're defined differently! (the more pedantic the better!)