# python class definition

Tags: python

some time i see some classes defined as subclass of object class, as

```
class my_class(object):
    pass
```

how is if different from the simple definition as

```
class my_class():
    pass
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332255/difference-between-class-foo-and-class-fooobject-in-python

Comment: In older versions of Python, the latter is a syntax error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This syntax declares a [new-style class](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes).

Comment: +∞: Oh look the question's already answered in the documentation.  I wish folks would read more and ask less.

Answer (score 4):

The first one is a new style class and the second is the old style class.

**EDIT**

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [2]: class B(object):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [3]: a = A()

In [4]: b = B()

In [5]: dir(a)
Out[5]: ['__doc__', '__module__']

In [6]: dir(b)
Out[6]: 
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__']
```

Comment: Does subclassing from object brings any inherited property to the class my_class ?

Answer (score 3):

For Python 3.x, there is no difference.  In Python 2.x, deriving from `object` makes a class [new-style](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/), while providing no base classes will give you an old-style class.

Answer (score 3):

For [new-style](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) classes in Python 2.x, you **MUST** explicitly inherit from `object`. Not declaring that a class inherit from `object` gives you an old-style class. In Python 3.x, explicitly inheriting from `object` is no longer required, so you can just declare in Python 3.x with Python 2.x old-style class syntax `class Klass: pass` and get back a new-style (or just a class) class.

Answer (score 2):

This is the "NEW" Style, and your question is similar to 
[Python class inherits object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object)